# How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find, pcregrep

I needed to find all the files that contained a specific string pattern. The first solution that comes to mind is using *find* piped with *xargs grep*:

```bash
find . -iname '*.py' | xargs grep -e 'YOUR_PATTERN'
```

But if I need to find patterns that spans on more than one line, I'm stuck because vanilla grep can't find multiline patterns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

Comment: This one's older, so I'd say it's not a duplicate :)

Comment: @rogerdpack When marking questions as duplicates, the age of a question is a tertiary concern, after the amount and quality of answers and the quality of the question.

Comment: Makes sense, voting to close since it's a "duplicate now"

Answer (score 109, accepted):

So I discovered [***pcregrep***](http://www.pcre.org/) which stands for **Perl Compatible Regular Expressions GREP**.

> the -M option makes it possible to search for patterns that span line boundaries.

For example, you need to find files where the '*_name*' variable is followed on the next line by the '*_description*' variable:

```bash
find . -iname '*.py' | xargs pcregrep -M '_name.*\n.*_description'
```

Tip: you need to include the line break character in your pattern. Depending on your platform, it could be '\n', \r', '\r\n', ...

Comment: As mentioned by halka below, "you can also persuade the dot wildcard to match newlines if you add (?s) to your regular expression". Then use grep with perl regex by adding -P. find . -exec  grep -nHP '(?s)SELECT.{1,60}FROM.{1,20}table_name' '{}' \;

Comment: `pcregrep` is available on the mac with `brew install pcre`

Comment: Even better: also use `-H` which prints the filename before each match: `pcregrep -HM`.

Comment: `pcregrep: line 1 of file /dev/fd/63 is too long for the internal buffer` when acting on a simple text file like `<(cat file.txt | tr '\0' '\n')`.

Answer (score 122):

Here is the example using [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/):

```bash
grep -Pzo '_name.*\n.*_description'
```

> `-z`/`--null-data` Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.

Which has the effect of treating the whole file as one large line.
See `-z` description [on grep's manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed/7167115#7167115) and also [common question no 14 on grep's manual usage page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Usage.html)

Comment: That only accounts for a single new-line character, I think.

Comment: I wasn't able to use grep for multiline search, without using flags `-z` so it doesn't split search on single line,  and `-o` to print only matched part.

Comment: I found that -o caused it to not print anything, but -l worked to get a list of files (my command was `grep -rzl pattern *`, -rzo didn't work)

Comment: I recommend ''**grep -Pazo**'' instead of ''-Pzo'' for non-ASCII files. It's better because the -z switch on non-ASCII files **may** trigger grep's "binary data" behaviour which changes the return values. Switch ''-a | --text'' prevents that.

Comment: Does not work on Mac with git installed by `brew reinstall --with-pcre git`

Answer (score 122):

Why don't you go for [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```bash
awk '/Start pattern/,/End pattern/' filename
```

Comment: This is much easier to understand and uses `awk` that comes with most *nix systems.

Comment: nice! is there a way to make this match non-greedy?

Comment: How would you only print the filename when there is a match?

Comment: You can show the line numbers of the matches with `awk '/Start pattern/,/End pattern/ {printf NR "  "; print}' filename`. You can make it prettier by giving the line numbers a fixed width: `awk '/Start pattern/,/End pattern/ {printf "%-4s  ", NR; print}' filename`.

Comment: This seems to work nicely on single file, however, what if I would like to search within multiple files?

Comment: @marcin, I just tried this with gnu awk 4.2.1 and it appears to be greedy only with regard to the Start pattern, by default, since it just search for the end pattern after finding the start pattern.

Comment: @Jinstrong use pipes. for example, `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -n1 awk '/foo/,/bar/'` will recursively search all txt files in the current directory.

Comment: Use grep to find the list of files which contain the basic word/words you're looking for, and then use awk to drill into each file via a for...in loop

Comment: Apparently making this non greedy is "non trivial" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49601/how-to-reduce-the-greediness-of-a-regular-expression-in-awk however the `pcregrep` command can do so.

Comment: Thanks for this! Helped me filter some log files that needed a multi-line match.

Comment: When I do this, my result contains the start/end pattern as well as what is inbetween these patterns. I am only interested in what is inbetween start and end (e.g., if the full string is `StartpatternStringEndpattern` I would like it to return `String`). Can this be done? The length of `String` varies.

Answer (score 25):

`grep -P` also uses libpcre, but is *much* more widely installed. To find a complete `title` section of an html document, even if it spans multiple lines, you can use this:

```bash
grep -P '(?s)<title>.*</title>' example.html
```

Since [the PCRE project](http://www.pcre.org/) implements to the perl standard, use the perl documentation for reference:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns

Comment: Hmm tried this just now and didn't seem to work... https://gist.github.com/rdp/0286d91624930bd11d0169d6a6337c33

Comment: I didn't know *grep* had this option. Probably because of this: *This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.*; that's under CentOS 7. Under Fedora 29: *This is experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features*. Of course in BSD grep it's not there at all. Would be nice if it wasn't so experimental but it's nice to be reminded of it - little though I'm likely to use it.

Comment: Works with `grep -Pzo` (though adds a trailing NUL char, see some of the other answers).  grep -P is common in "linux" but not BSD...

Answer (score 22):

Here is a more useful example:

```bash
pcregrep -Mi "<title>(.*\n){0,5}</title>" afile.html
```

It searches the title tag in a html file even if it spans up to 5 lines.

Here is an example of unlimited lines:

```bash
pcregrep -Mi "(?s)<title>.*</title>" example.html
```

Comment: thanks for this. I was stuck not realizing that a wildcard wouldn't match the newline character.

Comment: @matt: you can also persuade the dot wildcard to match newlines if you add `(?s)` to your regular expression, like so: `"(?s)<html>.*</html>"`

Comment: @matt Of course you can check for *`$`* (at the end of a pattern) to signify it's the end of the line - though that's not the same thing as helping you find multiple line patterns. See also *`glob(7)`*. You might also find this website of interest: https://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 11):

With [silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher):

```bash
ag 'abc.*(\n|.)*efg'
```

Speed optimizations of silver searcher could possibly shine here.

Answer (score 5):

This answer might be useful:

[Regex (grep) for multi-line search needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed/7167115#7167115)

To find recursively you can use flags -R (recursive) and --include (GLOB pattern). See:

[Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files/221929#221929)

Comment: @Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ note that editing a post in the LQP (https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19341146) invalidates the review, so just edit if you are sure the post needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 5):

@Marcin:
awk example non-greedy:

```bash
awk '{if ($0 ~ /Start pattern/) {triggered=1;}if (triggered) {print; if ($0 ~ /End pattern/) { exit;}}}' filename
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the grep alternative [sift](http://sift-tool.org) here (disclaimer: I am the author).

It support multiline matching and limiting the search to specific file types out of the box:

```bash
sift -m --files '*.py' 'YOUR_PATTERN'
```

(search all *.py files for the specified multiline regex pattern)

It is available for all major operating systems. Take a look at the [samples page](http://sift-tool.org/samples.html) to see how it can be used to  to extract multiline values from an XML file.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
perl -ne 'print if (/begin pattern/../end pattern/)' filename
```

Comment: This prints the whole file though

Comment: This worked for me, just the block I needed, on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ex`/`vi` editor and [globstar option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) (syntax similar to `awk` and `sed`):

```bash
ex +"/string1/,/string3/p" -R -scq! file.txt
```

where `aaa` is your starting point, and `bbb` is your ending text.

To search recursively, try:

```bash
ex +"/aaa/,/bbb/p" -scq! **/*.py
```

<sup>Note: To enable `**` syntax, run `shopt -s globstar` (Bash 4 or zsh).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As Amit's answer earlier, you can use awk to search for multiple lines. In case you need to print the line number, use the following:

```bash
awk '/Start pattern/,/End pattern/ {print NR ":" $0}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work and has the advantage of only using extended regular expressions without the need to install an extra tool like `pcregrep` if you don’t have it yet or don’t have the `-P` option to grep available (eg. macOS):

`egrep -irzo “.*aaa(.*\s.*){1,}.*bbb.*" path_to_filenames`

Caveat emptor: this does some slight disadvantages:

- it will find the largest selection of lines from the first `aaa` to the last `bbb` in each file, unless...
- there are several repetitions of the `aaa` [*stuff*] `bbb` pattern in each file.