# Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files

Tags: unix, search, shell, command-line, grep

I'm looking for the string `foo=` in text files in a directory tree. It's on a common Linux machine, I have bash shell:

```
grep -ircl "foo=" *
```

In the directories are also many binary files which match `"foo="`. As these results are not relevant and slow down the search, I want grep to skip searching these files (mostly JPEG and PNG images). How would I do that?

I know there are the `--exclude=PATTERN` and `--include=PATTERN` options, but what is the pattern format? The man page of grep says:

```
--include=PATTERN     Recurse in directories only searching file matching PATTERN.
--exclude=PATTERN     Recurse in directories skip file matching PATTERN.
```

Searching on *grep include*, *grep include exclude*, *grep exclude* and variants did not find anything relevant

If there's a better way of grepping only in certain files, I'm all for it; moving the offending files is not an option. I can't search only certain directories (the directory structure is a big mess, with everything everywhere). Also, I can't install anything, so I have to do with common tools (like *grep* or the suggested *find*).

Comment: Just FYI, the arguments used:

    -c count the matches in file
    -i case-insensitive
    -l only show matching files
    -r recursive

Comment: A quicker way to exclude svn dirs is `--exclude-dir=.svn`, so grep doesn't go into them at all

Comment: A couple of pedantic points people may need to know: 1. Note the lack of quotes around the glob here: --exclude='*.{png,jpg}' doesn't work (at least with my GNU grep version) because grep doesn't support {} in its globs.  The above is shell-expanded to '--exclude=*.png --exclude=*.jpg' (assuming no files match in the cwd - highly unlikely since you don't normally start filenames with '--exclude=') which grep likes just fine.  2. --exclude is a GNU extension and not part of POSIX's definition of grep, so if you write scripts using this be aware they won't necessarily run on non-GNU systems.

Comment: Full example of exclude-dir usage: `grep -r --exclude-dir=var "pattern" .`

Answer (score 949, accepted):

Use the shell [globbing syntax](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html):

```
grep pattern -r --include=\*.cpp --include=\*.h rootdir
```

The syntax for `--exclude` is identical.

Note that the star is escaped with a backslash to prevent it from being expanded by the shell (quoting it, such as `--include="*.cpp"`, would work just as well).  Otherwise, if you had any files in the current working directory that matched the pattern, the command line would expand to something like `grep pattern -r --include=foo.cpp --include=bar.cpp rootdir`, which would only search files named `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp`, which is quite likely not what you wanted.

**Update 2021-03-04**

I've edited the original answer to remove the use of [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), which is a feature provided by several shells such as Bash and zsh to simplify patterns like this; but note that brace expansion is not POSIX shell-compliant.

The original example was:

```
grep pattern -r --include=\*.{cpp,h} rootdir
```

to search through all `.cpp` and `.h` files rooted in the directory `rootdir`.

Comment: I don't know why, but I had to quote the include pattern like this: `grep pattern -r --include="*.{cpp,h}" rootdir`

Comment: @topek: Good point -- if you have any .cpp/.h files in your current directory, then the shell will expand the glob before invoking grep, so you'll end up with a command line like `grep pattern -r --include=foo.cpp --include=bar.h rootdir`, which will only search files named `foo.cpp` or `bar.h`.  If you don't have any files that match the glob in the current directory, then the shell passes on the glob to grep, which interprets it correctly.

Comment: I just realized that the glob is used to only matching the filename. To exclude a whole directory one needs `--exclude-dir` option. Same rules apply though. Only directory filename is matched, not a path.

Comment: `--include` doesn't seem to work after `--exclude`. I suppose it doesn't make sense to even try, except that I have an `alias` to grep with a long list of `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir`, which I use for searching code, ignoring libraries and swap files and things. I would've hoped that `grep -r --exclude='*.foo' --include='*.bar'` would work, so I could limit my `alias` to `--include='*.bar'` only, but it seems to ignore the `--include` and include everything that's not a .foo file. Swapping the order of the `--include` and `--exclude` works, but alas, that's not helpful with my `alias`.

Comment: how can we read someone's mind to get rules for this `PATTERN`. Half of hour I can't find any description of what are they waiting there for

Comment: For anyone sharing my frustration: single-item globs like `{sql}` don't match anything; you have to at least add a comma: `{sql,}`.

Comment: `{cpp,h}` is not a valid GLOB, how come this is accepted answer? `
`A pattern can use *, ?, and [...] as wildcards, and \ to quote a wildcard or backslash character literally`

Comment: @JakubBochenski That's a shell feature called *brace expansion* (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).  In this case, it's shorthand for `--include=\*.cpp --include=\*.h`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield it's not a shell feature, it's an extension of some shells like `bash` and will not work in plain POSIX shell

Comment: @JakubBochenski: Thanks, I wasn't aware that brace expansion wasn't a POSIX shell-compatible feature.  I've edited the original answer for clarity.

Comment: @WoodrowSigeru That fixes a symptom, but creates new problems. The proper fix is just to take out the braces if you only have one pattern.

Answer (score 237):

If you just want to skip binary files, I suggest you look at the `-I` (upper case i) option.  It ignores binary files.  I regularly use the following command:

```
grep -rI --exclude-dir="\.svn" "pattern" *
```

It searches recursively, ignores binary files, and doesn't look inside Subversion hidden folders, for whatever pattern I want.  I have it aliased as "grepsvn" on my box at work.

Comment: `--exclude-dir` is not available everywhere. my RH box at work with GNU grep 2.5.1 does not have it.

Comment: Any suggestions for what to use when `--exclude-dir` is unavailable? In all my attemps, `--exclude` does not appear to fit the bill.

Comment: You can always download the latest grep source from GNU, and do a  'configure; make; sudo make install'. This is one of the first things I do on a Mac or older Linunx distribution.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Actually, I use git. So, `--exclude-dir="\.git"`. :-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău git has a grep wrapper which searches only files that are indexed in your repository: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep

Answer (score 73):

Please take a look at [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/), which is designed for exactly these situations.  Your example of

```
grep -ircl --exclude=*.{png,jpg} "foo=" *
```

is done with ack as

```
ack -icl "foo="
```

because ack never looks in binary files by default, and -r is on by default.  And if you want only CPP and H files, then just do

```
ack -icl --cpp "foo="
```

Comment: Looks nice, will try the standalone Perl version next time, thanks.

Comment: Good call, I can no longer live without ack.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667471/how-do-i-run-programs-with-strawberry-perl - This will allow you to get ack on windows, if that is where you are running grep from.

Comment: @Chance Maybe you want [silversearcher-ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), just `apt-get` in Ubuntu :)

Comment: Ripgrep can also do this - ignores binary and git ignored files by default. To exclude a filetype, you use `rg --type-not cpp`, to search only for a filetype you use `rg --type cpp`. You can download just a single executable and run it.

Answer (score 37):

grep 2.5.3 introduced the `--exclude-dir` parameter which will work the way you want.

```
grep -rI --exclude-dir=\.svn PATTERN .
```

You can also set an environment variable: `GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude-dir=\.svn"`

I'll second [Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) vote for [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/) though, it's the best.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the exact version number; I have grep 2.5.1 and exclude-dir option is not available

Answer (score 33):

I found this after a long time, you can add multiple includes and excludes like:

```
grep "z-index" . --include=*.js --exclude=*js/lib/* --exclude=*.min.js
```

Comment: It is better to combine them in a list like : --exclude={pattern1,pattern2,pattern3}

Comment: make sure you add the --include/s before any --exclude/s

Answer (score 13):

The suggested command:

```
grep -Ir --exclude="*\.svn*" "pattern" *
```

is conceptually wrong, because --exclude works on the basename. Put in other words, it will skip only the .svn in the current directory.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work at all for me. The one that worked for me was: exclude-dir=.svn

Comment: @Nicola thank you! I've been tearing my hair out about why this won't work.  Tell me, is there a way to discover this from the manpage?  All it says is it matches "PATTERN".  *EDIT* manpage says "file", as explained here http://fixunix.com/unix/89433-why-does-%60grep-exclude%3D-svn%60-not-work.html#post293985

Answer (score 12):

In grep 2.5.1 you have to add this line to ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash profile

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude=\*.svn\*"
```

Answer (score 8):

I find grepping grep's output to be very helpful sometimes:

```
grep -rn "foo=" . | grep -v "Binary file"
```

Though, that doesn't actually stop it from searching the binary files.

Comment: You can use `grep -I` to skip binary files.

Comment: have also done that when i was young... now i know better and when confronted with a problem, first thing is RTFM

Comment: grepping grep will remove the color highlights.

Answer (score 7):

If you are not averse to using `find`, I like its `-prune` feature:

`find [directory] \
        -name "pattern_to_exclude" -prune \
     -o -name "another_pattern_to_exclude" -prune \
     -o -name "pattern_to_INCLUDE" -print0 \
| xargs -0 -I FILENAME grep -IR "pattern" FILENAME`

On the first line, you specify the directory you want to search. `.` (current directory) is a valid path, for example.

On the 2nd and 3rd lines, use `"*.png"`, `"*.gif"`, `"*.jpg"`, and so forth. Use as many of these `-o -name "..." -prune` constructs as you have patterns.

On the 4th line, you need another `-o` (it specifies "or" to `find`), the patterns you DO want, and you need either a `-print` or `-print0` at the end of it. If you just want "everything else" that remains after pruning the `*.gif`, `*.png`, etc. images, then use
`-o -print0` and you're done with the 4th line.

Finally, on the 5th line is the pipe to `xargs` which takes each of those resulting files and stores them in a variable `FILENAME`. It then passes `grep` the `-IR` flags, the `"pattern"`, and then `FILENAME` is expanded by `xargs` to become that list of filenames found by `find`.

For your particular question, the statement may look something like:

`find . \
     -name "*.png" -prune \
     -o -name "*.gif" -prune \
     -o -name "*.svn" -prune \
     -o -print0 | xargs -0 -I FILES grep -IR "foo=" FILES`

Comment: One amendment I'd suggest: include `-false` immediately after each `-prune` so forgetting to use `-print0` or some kind of `exec` command won't actually print the files you wanted to exclude: `-name "*.png" -prune -false -o name "*.gif -prune -false` ...

Answer (score 7):

On CentOS 6.6/Grep 2.6.3, I have to use it like this:

```
grep "term" -Hnir --include \*.php --exclude-dir "*excluded_dir*"
```

Notice the lack of equal signs "=" (otherwise `--include`, `--exclude`, `include-dir` and `--exclude-dir` are ignored)

Answer (score 6):

#### [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

Use `git grep` which is optimized for performance and aims to search through certain files.

By default it ignores binary files and it is honoring your `.gitignore`. If you're not working with Git structure, you can still use it by passing `--no-index`.

Example syntax:

```
git grep --no-index "some_pattern"
```

For more examples, see:

- [How to exclude certain directories/files from git grep search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10423143/55075).
- [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836697/55075)

Answer (score 5):

I'm a dilettante, granted, but here's how my ~/.bash_profile looks:

```bash
export GREP_OPTIONS="-orl --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.cache --color=auto" GREP_COLOR='1;32'
```

Note that to exclude two directories, I had to use --exclude-dir twice.

Comment: Necro comment from the distant dead .... GREP_OPTIONS is now deprecated, so I don't think these answers using that are valid anymore. Hey, I know it's late, but this is news to me. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you search non-recursively you can use [glop patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) to match the filenames.

```
grep "foo" *.{html,txt}
```

includes html and txt. It searches in the current directory only.

To search in the subdirectories:

```
grep "foo" */*.{html,txt}
```

In the subsubdirectories:

```
grep "foo" */*/*.{html,txt}
```

Answer (score 4):

find and xargs are your friends. Use them to filter the file list rather than grep's --exclude

Try something like

```
find . -not -name '*.png' -o -type f -print | xargs grep -icl "foo="
```

The advantage of getting used to this, is that it is expandable to other use cases, for example to count the lines in all non-png files:

```
find . -not -name '*.png' -o -type f -print | xargs wc -l
```

To remove all non-png files:

```
find . -not -name '*.png' -o -type f -print | xargs rm
```

etc.

As pointed out in the comments, if some files may have spaces in their names, use `-print0` and `xargs -0` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work on filenames with spaces, but that problem is easily solved by using print0 instead of print and adding the -0 option to xargs.

Answer (score 4):

> In the directories are also many binary files. I can't search only certain directories (the directory structure is a big mess). Is there's a better way of grepping only in certain files?

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

This is one of the quickest tools designed to recursively search your current directory. It is written in [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)), built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex) for maximum efficiency. Check the [detailed analysis here](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

So you can just run:

```
rg "some_pattern"
```

It respect your `.gitignore` and automatically skip hidden files/directories and binary files.

You can still customize include or exclude files and directories using `-g`/`--glob`. Globbing rules match `.gitignore` globs. Check `man rg` for help.

For more examples, see: [How to exclude some files not matching certain extensions with grep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441567/21471)

On macOS, you can install via `brew install ripgrep`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" -type f -print | xargs file | grep "foo=" | cut -d: -f1
```

Founded here: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/42573-search-files-excluding-binary-files.html

Comment: This doesn't work on filenames with spaces, but that problem is easily solved by using print0 instead of print and adding the -0 option to xargs.

Answer (score 2):

those scripts don't accomplish all the problem...Try this better:

```
du -ha | grep -i -o "\./.*" | grep -v "\.svn\|another_file\|another_folder" | xargs grep -i -n "$1"
```

this script is so better, because it uses "real" regular expressions to avoid directories from search. just separate folder or file names with "\|" on the grep -v

enjoy it!
found on my linux shell! XD

Answer (score 2):

Look @ this one.

```
grep --exclude="*\.svn*" -rn "foo=" * | grep -v Binary | grep -v tags
```

Comment: Things that achieve approximately this have been covered in other posts; what's more, this is wrong, in that with various layout options set it will mess up line numbers and things like that or exclude lines of context which were desired.

Answer (score 1):

The `--binary-files=without-match` option to GNU `grep` gets it to skip binary files.  (Equivalent to the `-I` switch mentioned elsewhere.)

(This might require a recent version of `grep`; 2.5.3 has it, at least.)

Answer (score 1):

suitable for tcsh .alias file:

```
alias gisrc 'grep -I -r -i --exclude="*\.svn*" --include="*\."{mm,m,h,cc,c} \!* *'
```

Took me a while to figure out that the {mm,m,h,cc,c} portion should NOT be inside quotes.
~Keith

Answer (score -1):

To ignore all binary results from grep

```
grep -Ri "pattern" * | awk '{if($1 != "Binary") print $0}'
```

The awk part will filter out all the Binary file foo matches lines

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

1. Create a folder named "`--F`" under currdir ..(or link another folder there renamed to "`--F`" ie `double-minus-F`.
2. `#> grep -i --exclude-dir="\-\-F"  "pattern" *`