# How do I run programs with Strawberry Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, ack, strawberry-perl

A coworker is trying to use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com) (a Perl program) on his Windows machine, having tried it under Linux and decided he definitely wants to use it.  He managed to get [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com) installed on his machine, but can't seem to figure out what to do to make ack run with it from a command prompt.  He tried editing the #! line, but I knew that wouldn't work.  I'm pretty sure Strawberry perl is in his PATH.

What do you need to do to run a general Perl program in your PATH on Windows using Strawberry?

Update: I'm seeing some information online about the PATHEXT variable, but not enough.

Comment: Withdrawing my answer since it's redundant and based on initially misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I wish you'd left it, Frakkle.  There was a useful piece of information in it for me, but I can't remember what it was!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, be careful that the program is in the `Path`, not just `perl.exe`.  The Perl binaries and core programs usually end up in `<installdir>\bin`, but others may end up in the site specific directory `<installdir>\site\bin`.  The command

```
dir C:\strawberry\ack* /s
```

might aid your search.  Make sure your `Path` reflects your setup.

There are two common ways, at least that I know of, to run a Perl program from the Windows Command Prompt.

The first is to create a batch version of the program with [pl2bat](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.10.0/win32/bin/pl2bat.pl), which will execute `perl` with the program. Installed programs usually do this automatically because `MakeMaker` and `Module::Build` take care of this.

The second is to create a `.pl` file association.  This is done by creating the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pl\Shell\Open\Command` (or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` if it's for the current user only) and set the `(Default)` value to

```
"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*
```

That way, you can call programs just by naming them with the `.pl` extension.  Now you can invoke the program with `program.pl`.

You may have noticed that you can call a program on Windows without the extension.  The program is searched for in the `Path`, but when there's no extension, `PATHEXT` is used to complete the name.  Append `.pl` to the list, and you can invoke the program just with `program`.  Note that the order in this list is important for the search, just as the order in `Path` matters.

Installers usually take care of the last two steps, but this knowledge is useful if you'd like to add your own or need to fix it.

Answer (score 17):

I haven't had a problem just installing ack and running it from the command line.

Is Strawberry Perl installed correctly?  Can you run "perl" from cmd.exe?

```
C:\> perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 0) configuration:
  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=5.1, archname=MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
...
```

Did App::Ack installed correctly?

```
C:\> cpan App::Ack
...
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\App\Ack.pm
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\App\Ack\Plugin.pm
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\App\Ack\Repository.pm
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\App\Ack\Resource.pm
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\App\Ack\Plugin\Basic.pm
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\bin\ack
Installing C:\strawberry\perl\bin\ack.bat
Writing C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\ack\.packlist
Appending installation info to C:\strawberry\perl\lib/perllocal.pod
  PETDANCE/ack-1.88.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE install UNINST=1 -- OK
```

If so, I don't see why you can't run "ack" from the command line:

```
C:\> ack --version
ack 1.88

Copyright 2005-2009 Andy Lester, all rights reserved.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
under the same terms as Perl itself.
```

If it isn't working, where in that chain are things broken?  For example, if you can't run "perl" from the command line, then Strawberry didn't install correctly (or isn't in your PATH) and you'll need to fix that.  But otherwise, ack gets installed with an "ack.bat" wrapper into the same path as "perl", so if you can run "perl" you should be able to run "ack".

Comment: We didn't install App::Ack ... we installed the standalone ack script.  I'll try install App::Ack through CPAN, and that'll probably work for this case, but I still want to know more generally how to make this work by modifying PATHEXT. :)

Comment: Yeah install App::Ack and then copy ack.bat from perl\site\bin into perl\bin (at least, that's what I had to do).  No real need to modify PATHEXT.

Comment: Thanks, xdg.  That got it running for us.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to create ack.exe with PAR::Packer - he would not need Strawberry at all.

Answer (score 0):

1.Install strawberry-perl
2.Open perl Commandline
3.Write command perl test.pl

[Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojs1L.png)