# Suppress find & grep "cannot open" output

Tags: unix, find, grep, filtering

I was given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027906/unix-find-grep-syntax-vs-awk) syntax by user [phi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45890/phi)

```
find . | awk '!/((\.jpeg)|(\.jpg)|(\.png))$/ {print $0;}' | xargs grep "B206"
```

I would like to suppress the output of grep: can't open..... and find: cannot open lines from the results.
sample output to be ignored:

```
grep: can't open ./cisc/.xdbhist
find: cannot open ./cisc/.ssh
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried redirecting stderr to /dev/null ?

```
2>/dev/null
```

So the above redirects stream no.2 (which is stderr) to /dev/null. That's shell dependent, but the above should work for most. Because find and grep are different processes, you may have to do it for both, or (perhaps) execute in a subshell. e.g.

```
find ... 2>/dev/null | xargs grep ... 2>/dev/null
```

[Here's](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Redirection) a reference to some documentation on bash redirection. Unless you're using csh, this should work for most.

Comment: im a little hesitant to try it out.... what does this do exactly?  it just doesn't seem like it will do what i need, but thats from a 370 talking to a 9,733

Comment: It simply causes all errors to be sent to /dev/null, where they will be ignored.

Comment: It makes the assumption (which I've not checked, I confess) that your errors above come out on std err. 2>/dev/null will redirect errors to /dev/null (a bin) in the same way that (say) find ... > /tmp/find.results would redirect std out to a file

Comment: find .  2>/dev/null | awk '!/((\.jpeg)|(\.jpg)|(\.png))$/ {print $0;}' | xargs grep "B206" 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 9):

The option flag grep -s will suppress these messages for the grep command