# How to specify ignore pattern in grep?

Tags: linux, grep

How can I make grep to ignore some files (e.g. .svn directories, binary files, etc.) while grepping recursively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an --exclude pattern as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files)

Answer (score 2):

Use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

Comment: The issue asks for a solution in grep, not for a tool to achieve the same