# How to limit grep to only search the files that you want

Tags: unix, grep, find

We have a rather large and complex file system and I am trying to generate a list of files containing a particular text string. This should be simple, but I need to exclude the './svn' and './pdv' directories (and probably others) and to only look at files of type *.p, *.w or *.i*.

I can easily do this with a program, but it is proving very slow to run. I want to speed up the process (so that I'm not searching thousands of files repeatedly) as I need to run such searches against a long list of criteria.

Normally, we search the file system using:

```
find . -name "*.[!r]*" -exec grep -i -l "search for me" {} \;
```

This is working, but I'm then having to use a program to exclude the unwanted directories , so it is running very slowly.

After looking at the topics here:
[Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files)

I've decided to try a few other aproaches:

```
grep -ilR "search for me" . --exclude ".svn" --excluse "pdv" --exclude "!.{p,w,i*}"
```

Excludes the './svn', but not the './pdv' directories, Doesn't limit the files looked at.

```
grep -ilR "search for me" . --exclude ".svn" --excluse "pdv" --include "*.p"
```

Excludes the './svn', but not the './pdv' directories, Doesn't limit the files looked at.

```
find . -name "*.[!r]*" -exec grep -i -l ".svn" | grep -i -l "search for me" {} \;
```

I can't even get this (or variations on it) to run successfully.

```
find . ! -name "*.svn*" -prune -print -exec grep -i -l "search for me" {} \;
```

Doesn't return anything. It looks like it stops as soon as it finds the .svn directory.

Comment: Explicitly, I'm looking for all files that match any of "*.p", "*.w" or "*.i*" and excluding the directories called ".svn" and "pdv". Many thanks

Comment: In your examples are `--excluse "pdv"` (note the typo s/d) in both cases and you are complaining about that particular condition not working... just checking typo is not the main problem.

Comment: Well, I think that "D'Oh!" is a good start. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @geronime, I just tried that example with the typo fixed (I hope). The search string is `grep -ilR "run" . --exclude ".svn" --exclude "pdv" --exclude "!.{p,w,i*}"`.  Unfortunately as the results set now includes both  `.svn/text-base/jr83144.p.svn-base`  and  `pdv/cm/backupds.i`  I don't think that this has worked.  Many thanks

Comment: have you rather tried `--exclude-dir` parameter? That is actually the problem I think. Refer to the manual of `grep`.

Comment: To exclude directories: `find . \( \( -name .svn -o -name pdv \) -type d -prune \) -o \( -name '*.[pwi]' -exec grep ... {} + \)`

Comment: @geronime, I've tried `--exclude-dir`, but it didn't appear to register. Neither it, nor `--exclude` are listed in teh manual.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks to all of you for your help. Even where an answer's not worked, it's giving me a good insite to how grep and find work.

Comment: @Colin: I see, you were not talking about linux. The `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir` are advanced options of `grep` implemented on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
find . \( \( -name .svn -o -name pdv \) -type d -prune \) -o \( -name '*.[pwi]' -type f -exec grep -i -l "search for me" {} + \)
```

This will:
- ignore the contents of directories named .svn and pdv
- grep files (and symlinks to files) named *.[pwi]

The `+` option after `exec` means gather as many files into a single command as will fit on the command line (roughly 1 million chars in Linux).  This can seriously speed up processing if you have to iterate over thousands of files.

Answer (score 2):

Following command finds only *.rb files containing `require 'bundler/setup'` line and excludes search in `.git` and `.bundle` directories. That is the same use case I think.

```
grep -ril --exclude-dir .git --exclude-dir .bundle \
  --include \*.rb "^require 'bundler/setup'$" .
```

The problem was with swapping of `--exclude` and `--exclude-dir` parameters I believe. Refer to the `grep(1)` manual.

Also note that exclude/include parameters accept `GLOB` only, not regexps, therefore single character suffix range can be done with one `--include` parameter, but more complex conditions would require more of the parameters:

```
--include \*.[pwi] --include \*.multichar_sfx ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
find path_starting_point -type f | grep regex_to_filter_file_names | xargs grep regex_to_find_inside_matched_files
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't the the "regex_to_filter_file_names" to work properly. I've tried `find . -type f | grep .*\.p | xargs -il grep "run"`, but it's returning files ending .ixx as well as ending .p.

Comment: maybe `grep '\.\[pwi\]$'` to match files ending with "_.p_", "_.w_" or "_.i_" suffix

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "filename_regex"|grep -v '.svn' -v '.pdv'|xargs grep -i 'your search string'
```

Comment: I've also given this a try, but again can't get the regex to work. Just using a simple example of `find . -name ".*\.i"` to try out the concept isn't returning any values.