# How do I use grep to search the current directory for all files having the a string "hello" yet display only .h and .cc files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

How do I use grep to search the current directory for any and all files containing the string "hello" and display only .h and .cc files?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
grep -r --include=*.{cc,h} "hello" .
```

This reads: search recursively (in all sub directories also) for all .cc OR .h files that contain "hello" at this `.` (current) directory

[From another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files)

Comment: In the original post you said "current directory" and nothing about needing it recursively or in sub directories (I realize you mentioned it in a later post).  For those interested in how to do it only in the current directory, it's `grep -si "hello" --include=*.{cc,h} ./* ./.*`(searches hidden files as well).  Here's a generic version to search for a string in all/hidden files: `grep -s "hello" * .*` .  Maybe most *generally* useful (and simplest), this searches all non-hidden files for "hello": `grep -si "hello" ./*`  Thanks to this post: http://askubuntu.com/a/777456

Comment: `grep -r --include=*.{java,py} "hello" .`

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work on macOS, even when using the GNU grep utility.

Answer (score 60):

You can pass in wildcards in instead of specifying file names or using stdin.

```
grep hello *.h *.cc
```

Comment: I need all sub directories also

Comment: Adding `-R` doesn't work unfortunately. It expands the `*` before going recursively.

Comment: Noufal's answer is what you are looking for if you need subdirectories

Comment: @Jammin You should be clear about that when asking the question. This answer is the "correct" answer to your stated question.

Comment: `$ grep -R hello *` # find from all the word contain hello (including sub directory)

Answer (score 31):

To search in current directory recursively:

```
grep -r 'myString' .
```

Answer (score 21):

`find . -name \*.cc -print0 -or -name \*.h -print0 | xargs -0 grep "hello"`.

Check the manual pages for `find` and `xargs` for details.

Comment: You have to have a `-print0` after the `'*.cc'` as otherwise you don't have an action for that part of the search.  Or you have to insert parentheses in there: `find . \( -name '*.cc' -or -name '*.h' \) -print0`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I've edited the answer to "fix" it.

Comment: You can also use the `find -exec +` syntax instead of xargs

Comment: @jordanm: Yes: `-exec grep "hello" {} +` where the pair of braces represents the file name(s).  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

If I read your question carefully, you ask to "grep to search the current directory for ***any and all files*** containing the string "hello" and display only .h and .cc files".  So to meet your precise requirements here is my submission:

This displays the file names:

```
grep -lR hello * | egrep '(cc|h)$'
```

...and this display the file names and contents:

```
grep hello `grep -lR hello * | egrep '(cc|h)$'`
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need a recursive search, you have a variety of options.  You should consider [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com/).

Failing that, if you have GNU `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.cc' -print0 -o -name '*.h' -print0 | xargs -0 grep hello /dev/null
```

The use of `/dev/null` ensures you get file names printed; the `-print0` and `-0` deals with file names containing spaces (newlines, etc).

If you don't have obstreperous names (with spaces etc), you can use:

```
find . -name '*.*[ch]' -print | xargs grep hello /dev/null
```

This might pick up a few names you didn't intend, because the pattern match is fuzzier (but simpler), but otherwise works.  And it works with non-GNU versions of `find` and `xargs`.

Comment: note you can also say `find ... -exec grep "hello" {} +`

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -l hello **/*.{h,cc}
```

You might want to `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid error messages if there are no .h or no .cc files.

Comment: I know how to use google etc. I asked it here because several answers have "-l" and it's nice to have all the information in one place.

Comment: -l (Lowercase "el") 
Suppresses normal output. Prints the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning/searching will stop on the first match.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way : grep -Ril "Your text" /

Comment: This doesn't display only .h or .cc files and it is useful to explain which options you used and why.