# Surprising GREP Behavior

Tags: macos, grep, pipe, zsh, ls

I have a directory that contains the following

```
Applications  Desktop   Documents   Downloads   Dropbox (Personal)
Google Drive   Library   Movies   Music   Pictures   Public
```

I am trying to learn how to use `grep` by playing around with it, and uncovered the following surprising result when I piped the output of `ls` into `grep`:

`ls | grep D*` returns:

```
grep: Documents: Is a directory
grep: Downloads: Is a directory
grep: Dropbox (personal): Is a directory
grep: Google Drive: Is a directory
```

But when I do `ls | grep Do*` I get the following:

```
grep: Downloads: Is a directory
```

Why doesn't `ls | grep Do*` return the `Documents` folder as well? As in:

```
grep: Documents: Is a directory
grep: Downloads: Is a directory
```

Lastly, this question is different than the questions and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217185/how-do-i-use-grep-to-search-the-current-directory-for-all-files-having-the-a-str#) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files). I'm not looking for a way to solve this problem by switching to `awk` or passing flags to `grep`: instead, I'm looking to understand the underlying behavior of `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I do `ls | grep Do*` I get the following:

That's because the `Do*` gets expanded by the shell into `Documents Downloads Dropbox (Personal)`.

You're doing the `grep`ping all wrong. If you want a filename that starts with `D` then you would do `ls | grep ^D`. grep uses regular expressions, not file globbing.

Also, you should not be using `ls` and `grep` to find files. If you want to find files that start with `D` then use `find . -name 'D*'`.