# how do I use the grep --include option for multiple file types?

Tags: shell, grep

When I want to grep all the html files in some directory, I do the following

`grep --include="*.html" pattern -R /some/path`

which works well. The problem is how to grep all the html,htm,php files in some directory?

From this [Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files), it seems that I can do the following

`grep --include="*.{html,php,htm}" pattern -R /some/path`

But sadly, it would not work for me.
FYI, my grep version is 2.5.1.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You can use multiple `--include` flags. This works for me:

```sh
grep -r --include=*.html --include=*.php --include=*.htm "pattern" /some/path/
```

However, you can do as [Deruijter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619274). This works for me:

```sh
grep -r --include=*.{html,php,htm} "pattern" /some/path/
```

Don't forget that you can use `find` and `xargs` for this sort of thing too:

```sh
find /some/path/ -name "*.htm*" -or -name "*.php" | xargs grep "pattern"
```

Comment: I see the problem. I used --include="*.{html,php}" to prevent shell from expanding '*' which at the same time stop shell to expand {html,php}. It seems that equal sign in --include=* is able to prevent shell from expanding '*'.

Comment: xargs isn't really a substitute; lots of times when you need this feature, you're dealing with more files than xargs will handle.

Comment: @JamesMoore: Take a look at [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It can often be used as a substitute for `xargs`. [This](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#differences_between_xargs_and_gnu_parallel) is also worth a quick read. HTH.

Comment: @tianyapiaozi: You are correct that the quoting around the brace expansion is the problem; without the quoting, however, `*` is still subject to globbing _as part of the token it is embedded in_, it just _happens_ not to match anything in this case, because only files _literally_ named something like `--include=foo.html` would match. To be safe, quote the `*` (which can you do individually with `\*`). As an added bonus this makes it _visually_ clearer that is _not the shell_ that should perform the globbing in this case.

Comment: As for the `find` solution: using `-exec grep "pattern" {} +` instead of `| xargs grep "pattern"` is more robust (handles filenames with spaces, for instance) as well as more efficient.

Comment: what @mklement0 wrote is true, especially because find with -exec is aware of the maximum command-line length accepted by xargs and will chunk the file names and keep the xargs command length legal, while using a pipe can exceed the maximum command line length

Comment: @simpleuser: To be clear: you'd use `-exec` _instead_ of `xargs` - `find -exec` has `xargs` logic _built in_ (perhaps that's what you meant). As for pipes: as long as the arguments flow via stdin as opposed to being passed on the command line (whether with or without a pipeline), there shouldn't be a problem (due to `xargs`' intelligent behind-the-scenes argument chunking).

Answer (score 47):

**tl;dr**

```
# Works in bash, ksh, and zsh.
grep -R '--include=*.'{html,php,htm} pattern /some/path
```

---

Using **`{html,php,htm}` can only work as a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion)**, which is a nonstandard (not POSIX-compliant) feature of `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`.

- In other words: do not try to use it in a script that targets `/bin/sh` - use *explicit* multiple `--include` arguments in that case.
- **`grep` itself does *not* understand `{...}` notation.**

For a brace expansion to be recognized, it **must be an *unquoted* (part of a) token** on the command line.

A brace expansion **expands to *multiple arguments***, so in the case at hand **`grep` ends up seeing *multiple* `--include=...` options**, just as if you had passed them individually.

The results of a brace expansion are **subject to globbing (filename expansion)**, which has **pitfalls**:

- Each resulting argument could further be expanded to matching filenames if it happens to contain *unquoted* globbing metacharacters such as `*`.
  While this is unlikely with tokens such as `--include=*.html` (e.g., you'd have to have a file *literally named* something like `--include=foo.html` for something to match), it is worth keeping in mind in general.
- If the `nullglob` shell option happens to be turned on (`shopt -s nullglob`) and globbing matches *nothing*, the argument will be *discarded*.

Therefore, for **a fully robust solution**, use the following:

```
grep -R '--include=*.'{html,php,htm} pattern /some/path
```

- `'--include=*.'` is treated as a *literal*, due to being *single-quoted*; this prevents inadvertent interpretation of `*` as a globbing character.
- `{html,php,htm}`, the - of necessity - *unquoted* brace expansion<sup>[1]</sup>
  , expands to *3* arguments, which, due to `{...}` *directly following the `'...'` token*, *include* that token.
- Therefore, after quote removal by the shell, **the following *3* *literal* arguments are ultimately passed to `grep`**:

  - `--include=*.html`
  - `--include=*.php`
  - `--include=*.htm`

---

<sup>[1] More accurately, it's only the *syntax-relevant* parts of the brace expansion that must be unquoted, the *list elements* may still be individually quoted and must be if they contain globbing metacharacters that could result in unwanted globbing after the brace expansion; while not necessary in this case, the above could be written as

`'--include=*.'{'html','php','htm'}`</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for this post. Great posts not only answer the question but teach you something new! This is especially useful for those of us writing on something that needs to be POSIX compliant. Anybody using Mac OS X should look here!

Comment: @sabalaba: I'm glad to hear it, but to be clear: while brace expansion is not POSIX-compliant, it works with `bash` on any platform that `bash` runs on.

Comment: I also need to use a file type that has no extension. `--include={\*.yaml,dockerfile}`

Comment: @AmitNaidu, as long as your extension-less files can be _individually enumerated by their literal names_, that works, as in your example with `dockerfile`. However, there is no _wildcard_ pattern I am aware of that would abstractly match _any_ extension-less filename.

Answer (score 11):

Try removing the double quotes

```
grep --include=*.{html,php,htm} pattern -R /some/path
```

Comment: @tianyapiaozi Try `grep --include=\*.{html,php,htm} pattern -R /some/path`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

is this not working?

```
  grep pattern  /some/path/*.{html,php,htm}
```

Comment: Not really. The files may by reside in subdirectory of subdirectory

Answer (score 5):

It works for the same purpose, but without `--include` option. It works on grep 2.5.1 as well.

```
grep -v -E ".*\.(html|htm|php)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
-r will do a recursive search.
-s will suppress file not found errors.
-n will show you the line number of the file where the pattern is found.

```
    grep "pattern" <path> -r -s -n --include=*.{c,cpp,C,h}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me particularly, and I think you can put -rsn instead of -r -s -n (but that's nitpicking).

Comment: Usually I use **-rns**. For clarity in the example I had to mention **-r -n -s** :-) Glad that it helped.

Comment: I recommend adding `-I` to the standard set. It skips binary files (which are hardly ever searched) hence boosts efficiency. Then we go `grep -rIns ...` which acousticly plays nicely:)

Comment: This does search through every file, not just the ones that match the expression regex.  It's accurate, but not efficient when you know the extension, or another way to identify the file by name.

Comment: @wexxor, there is no regex here, but you may be using a shell that doesn't support brace expansion. Or your shell may be globbing the unquoted `*` or causing grep to discard the `--include` option completely. To hide them from the shell, you should always single quote or escape glob characters, which will prevent this: `--include=\*.{c,h}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` with `find` command

```
find /some/path -name '*.html' -o -name '*.htm' -o -name '*.php' -type f 
 -exec grep PATTERN {} \+
```

You can use `-regex` and `-regextype` options too.