# how to exclude multiple pattern using grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep, command

I want to exclude both `"*log*"` and `./tags` from grep.

What i do is:

```
grep -rI "PatternToSearch" ./path --exclude="*log*"
```

or this:

```
grep -rI "PatternToSearch" ./path --exclude="tags"
```

is it possible to merge both exclude patterns in one grep?

Comment: You could also construe it using `find`, with something like `find . -name ./tags -prune -o -not -name "*log*" -exec grep -HI Pattern {} +`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try below:

```
 grep -rI "PatternToSearch" ./path --exclude={*log*,tags}
```

Just use "," to separate patterns.

Seems duplicated with [how do I use the grep --include option for multiple file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619160/how-do-i-use-the-grep-include-option-for-multiple-file-types)

Answer (score 3):

Have another `--exclude <pattern>`:

```
grep -rI "PatternToSearch" --exclude="*log*" --exclude="tags" .
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava it worked, but curious to know if there's any other way where i write `--exclude` only once

Comment: Unfortunately `--exclude` doesn't allow regex or extended pattern to specify more than 1 pattern in single option.

Comment: You can use `--exclude={*log*,tags}` to ignore more than 1 pattern with --exclude.