# Weird issue when running grep with the --include option

Tags: bash, shell, grep, brace-expansion

Here is the code at the bash shell.  How is the file mask supposed to be specified, if not this way?  I expected both commands to find the search expression, but it's not happening. In this example, I know in advance that I prefer to restrict the search to python source code files only, because unqualified searches are silly time wasters.

So, this works as expected:

```
grep -rni '/home/ga/projects' -e 'def Pr(x,u,v)'
```

> /home/ga/projects/anom/anom.py:27:def Pr(x,u,v): blah, blah, ...

but this won't work:

```
grep --include=\*.{py} -rni '/home/ga/projects' -e 'def Pr(x,u,v)'
```

I'm using GNU `grep` version 2.16.

Comment: What do you think the braces around `py` are doing?

Comment: A list containing 1 or more items has been a useful artifact in my past work here. Depending on the day and the problem, I have 1 or more file extensions to search through, e.g., .py today, .py and .ipynb tomorrow, .R some other day, and then .R and .Rmd and .ipynb on the 4th day because jupyter now supports R code but the ipynb extension is still there despite, which is a legacy thing due to the genesis of jupyter being in the ipython codebase originally but not any more.

Comment: Brace expansion doesn't support 1-item lists. Those braces are being passed to `grep` literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--include=\*.{py}` looks like a ***broken attempt* to use *brace expansion*** (an *unquoted* `{...}` expression).

However, for [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion)
 to occur in `bash` (and `ksh` and `zsh`), you must either have:

- a *list* of *at least 2* items, separated with `,`; e.g. `{py,txt}`, which expands to *2* arguments, `py` and `txt`.
- or, a *range* of items formed from two end points, separated with `..`; e.g., `{1..3}`, which expands to *3* arguments, `1`, `2`, and `3`.

Thus, **with a *single* item, simply do not use brace expansion**:

```
--include=\*.py
```

If you did have multiple extensions to consider, e.g., `*.py` as well as `*.pyc` files, here's a robust form that illustrates the underlying shell features:

```
'--include=*.'{py,pyc}
```

Here:

- Brace expansion *is* applied, because `{...}` contains a 2-item list.
- Since the `{...}` *directly* follows the *literal* (single-quoted) string `--include=*.`, the results of the brace expansion *include* the literal part.
- Therefore, *2* arguments are ultimately passed to `grep`, with the following *literal* content:

  - `--include=*.py`
  - `--include=*.pyc`

Comment: @PauloMattos: Thanks, though I wouldn't necessarily call it a _hack_ - it's a regular application of brace expansion.

Comment: Agreed. I discovered the command finally worked correctly, before checking back at this website, when I removed the braces, when there is only a single item to search for.

Answer (score 2):

Your command fails because of the braces '{}'. It will search for it in the file name. You can create a file such as 'myscript.{py}' to convince yourself. You'll see it will appear in the results.

The correct option parameter would be `'*.py'` or the equivalent `\*.py`. Either way will protect it from being (mis)interpreted by the shell.

On the other side, I can only advise to use the command find for such jobs :

```
find /home/ga/projects -regex '.*\.py$' -exec grep -e "def Pr(x,u,v)" {} +
```

That will protect you from hard to understand shell behaviour.

Comment: Using a backslash is equivalent to using quotes — it protects the string from misinterpretation.  That said, `--include=*.py` (no quotes, no backslashes) would work unless you have a file called, for example, `--include=abc.py` in your directory, which is pretty implausible (or you set your shell options inappropriately).

Comment: If you're going to use `find`, use `+` in place of `\;` so that `find` runs `grep` as infrequently as possible (rather than once per matching file name which the semicolon requires).

Comment: Anything involving finding files is not "pure grep", it's an ugly hack provided by the GNU guys for reasons beyond mortal ken. `grep` was created to `Globally find a Regular Expression in a file and Print the result`. There already was (and still is) a perfectly good tool for `find`ing files before the GNU guys muddied the waters.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this (using *quotes* to be safe; also better readability than *backslash* escaping IMHO):

```
grep --include='*.py' ...
```

your `\*.{py}` *brace expansion* usage isn't supported *at all* by `grep`. Please see the comments below for the full investigation regarding this. For the record, blame [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628271/819340) for the resulting brace wars ;)

By the way, the brace expansion works generally fine in Bash. See [mklement0 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44120181/819340) for more details.

---

**Ack**. As an alternative, you might consider switching to [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com) instead from now on. It's a tool just like `grep`, but fully optimized for programmers.

It's a great fit for what you are doing. A nice *quote* about it:

> Every once in a while something comes along that improves an idea so much, you can't ignore it. Such a thing is `ack`, the `grep` replacement.

Comment: Do the braces really only work when there's at least one comma?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was surprised too :( But I tested on macOS and it really matters...

Comment: ...and I'm seeing this same behavior in pure Bash *expansion* as well (e.g., `echo *.py` not the same as `echo *.{py}`; the latter just outputs `*.{py}`.)

Comment: Curious — it does indeed matter.  Bash (3.2.57 — distributed by default on macOS Sierra 10.12.5; also Bash 4.3.42) requires a comma too, much to my surprise.  At least `grep` is consistent with Bash.

Comment: I don't think `grep` understands the `{}` syntax at all. `grep --include='*.{py,html,php}'` will match only files that _literally_ have extension `.{py,html,php}`. Without quoting, only Bash comes into play, and, indeed, the list form of brace expansion requires a comma.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Running **Bash 3.2.57(1)-release** here... man, that pretty much summarizes my *love and hate* relationship with Bash :-(

Comment: @mklement0: You seem to be correct — the braces work with commas in Bash but not in `grep`, and the braces don't work as you'd expect in Bash when there isn't at least one comma (or a range expression).  A curious piece of non-generality, but [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is pretty weird/limited anyway.  (Am I allowed to add 'but it comes from C shell, which is pretty weird/limited too'?)

Comment: @mklement0 I think you are right man! I'm running more tests here, on macOS Sierra, and indeed the `'*.{py,html,php}'` isn't working at all with `grep`.

Comment: Interesting about macOS vs other Unix.  I wonder if it depends on whether the POSIX-based library function [`fnmatch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html) supports the notation, or whether `grep` builds it into its own code.  Or whether the other answer was produced under the influence — I just dug out a Centos 7 VM and `grep --include='*.{c,h}' -rlw -e include .` printed nothing, but not using the braces (once, `.c` only; twice, `.c` and `.h`) worked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ...as someone once noted: *"The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from."* :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Re weirdness: while the single-item issue is debatable, it's the inability to use _variable references_ to drive a range expansion that makes range brace expansions awkward. Only `bash` has this limitation, however - both `ksh` and `zsh` do support variables in that scenario.

Comment: @mklement0: It's messy, but you're right.  `printf '%s\n' /opt/gnu/bin/grep -r -l -w -e include --include=*.{c,h} .` generates output including `--include=*.c` and `--include=*.h`; file name generation at work. With `--include=*.{c}`, the output includes `--include=*.{c}`; file name generation not working. Having created `> '--include=abc.h'`, the first variant generates `--include=*.c` and 
`--include=abc.h` — this drives beginners to despair (and old hands to the bar). Does `tcsh` allow variables in brace expansion ranges? No: `set x=5 y=9` and `echo abc.{$x..$y}` yields `abc.5..9`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for that. I've just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121121/45375) to the linked question that tries to cover these subtleties.