# gnu grep --include file extension case sensitivity

Tags: windows, grep, gnu

I am on Windows 10, using GNU grep 2.10.

**Update:** The question has been answered, but I now realize the premise of this question is wrong, because it turns out I must've had some typo that I didn't see even after re-reading my commands multiple times. There is nothing wrong with the grep included in nuwen.net. Thank you Stephan T. Lavavej. I will keep this answer up because it still taught me something that the previous question (linked below) did not.

**Original question as follows:**

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619160/how-do-i-use-the-grep-include-option-for-multiple-file-types), multiple --include statements can be used to search multiple file extensions.

However, I experienced an issue when I have multiple file extensions that only differ in capitalization.

```
grep -ri "foo" --include="*.h" --include="*.H" .
```

The above command will only search through .h files, and not .H files.

```
grep -ri "foo" --include="*.H" --include="*.h" .
```

The above command now will only search through .H files, and not .h files.

So apparently, it is only processing the first --include argument because it considers the second to be a duplicate, but then it doesn't search both .H and .h.

**My question is:** How do I get GNU grep on Windows to search both (and only both) file extensions?

Comment: From where did you get a Windows version of GNU grep 2.10? I cannot reproduce this with GNU grep 2.5.4 from GnuWin32. Anyway, try `grep -ri "foo" --include="*.[Hh]"`.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I had tried doing the {Hh} syntax, but didn't know about the [Hh] syntax. If you want to write that as an answer, I'll certainly accept it.

Comment: To answer your question: I did some research. I have been using the grep that came bundled with the MinGW download in https://nuwen.net/mingw.html from June 2017, meaning that it had a grep version from 2012, according to the version history. I believe the author of the website may have custom built it themselves from the following link: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/ but I am not certain. The current version on their website says it uses grep 3.1, and the bug no longer exists (although now it uses different highlighting colors that I don't like, but that's off-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try

```
grep -ri "foo" --include="*.[Hh]"
```

which should search both files ending in `H` and those ending in `h`. The [manual page for `grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) says

> A pattern can use `*`, `?`, and `[`...`]`  as wildcards, and `\` to  quote a wildcard or backslash character literally.