# Search File Server for all files with email address using GREP

Tags: terminal, grep, zsh

There has been a data breach and I need to find all file paths across a file server with email addresses.

I was trying

```
grep -lr --include='*.{csv,xls,xlsx,txt}' "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" * >output.txt
```

But, this is returning nothing.

I would be grateful for an suggestions. thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly try to do here ? Find all the files containing an email address ?

Comment: containing any email address

Answer (score 0):

Your grep command is almost correct, there is only small glitches that make it not working.

First, for matching your email regex, you should use grep's extended regex option `-E`.

Next, as explained [in this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121121/6807769), your `--include` pattern will not work in zsh. You need to put your ending quote before the braces, as follow: `--include='*.'{csv,xls,xlsx,txt}`

Finally, if you want to get all files on the server, you should perform this command on root directory `/` instead of on all files/directories present in the directory you are when you execute the command as you do with `*`

**So your grep command should be:**

```sh
grep -Elr --include='*.'{csv,xls,xlsx,txt} "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" /
```

Some points to take into account:

- you will not detect email in excel files `.xls` and `.xlsx` as they are binary files so grep will not be able to parse them.
- [email pattern matching is rather hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/6807769), there are a lot of special cases in email parsing. The email pattern you're currently using will catch almost all emails, but not all of them.