# How do you exclude a specific file from ack (ack-grep)?

Tags: ack

With the normal `grep` command there is an `--exclude` option (covered in detail here: [Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files)) that lets you ignore specific files when you are grepping.

Ack's `--type` option takes care of 95% of the cases where you'd want to exclude files, but it doesn't (as far as I can tell) handle the case of excluding a specific file.  I've got a compiled JS file that has the contents of every other JS file in it (on a single line), so every time I grep for *anything* I get back the entire contents of that giant compiled file.

I'd hate to have to give up on ack and go back to grep over this, but it is *really* annoying.  Please, someone tell me there's a way to exclude specific files from ack searches.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, ack 1.x will not let you exclude a single file.  In [ack 2.0](https://github.com/petdance/ack2), you can.  ack 2.0 <strike>was currently in its first alpha</strike> is now the current recommended version of ack.

As far as your specific case of the minified Javascript file, what version of ack are you using?  ack 1.96 should ignore minified JavaScript based on extension.  If the extension check doesn't work, you could probably hack ack itself, since it's a single Perl program.  You can hack the `is_searchable` function.

In ack 2.0, we're looking at ignoring any line over, say, 500 characters because it's clearly not source code.

You may also want to join us on the [ack-users](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/ack-users) mailing list.  We're pretty responsive.

Comment: In fact, my next stop was going to be the ack mailing list, but I figured I'd check here first to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious :-)  Thanks Andy.

Comment: P.S. I'm choosing the filename for my compiled JS file, so at the moment it's just built.js.  I'll try renaming it to built.min.js and see if that helps.

Answer (score 120):

To ignore a single file using ack 2.0, provide a filter spec to the --ignore-file flag:

`--ignore-file=is:cljout.js`

Comment: What is the `is:` doing here?

Comment: Exact filename match. http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.04-man.html#is_filename

Comment: This works for me on filenames, but not if I want to give a specific file (i.e. path and filename).

Comment: How to specify multiple?

Comment: You can use `match` along with a regex to match filenames and `ext` for extensions. Exclude js files `--ignore-file=ext:js`. Exclude files with name foo and bar `--ignore-file='match:/foo|bar/'`. Escape the parameter with quotes in case of regex with `|` so that shell doesn't execute it as a pipe.

Comment: This whole `is:` thing is so not obvious and annoying

Comment: Doesn't make it easy to split on a path, e.g. it would be useful to use a different delimiter: `--ignore-file='match:#path/to/thing/whatever.ext#'`

Comment: For those who find the `--ignore-file` syntax too `awk`ward, you could use something like this:
`REGEX='find.*stuff'; ack "$REGEX" -l | ack -v bad_file | ack --files-from - "$REGEX"`
which will search and output just the filenames, then filter out filenames with the word 'bad_file', then do the search again only on the files that are left

Answer (score 30):

If you run `ack --create-ackrc` it will output a whole bunch of presets for common files like minified javascript, css and directories like node_modules and .git. Very useful!

Here's the minified js option:

```
# minified Javascript
--ignore-file=match:/[.-]min[.]js$/
--ignore-file=match:/[.]js[.]min$
```

And here's how to ignore a directory called foo:

```
--ignore-directory=is:foo
```

If you want to save this to `.ackrc` run

```
ack --create-ackrc >> ~/.ackrc
```

and then delete what you don't need from that file.

Also, you can create another `.ackrc` file in your project's root folder for project specific stuff. I put that in `.gitignore` so it doesn't clutter the repo.

Comment: I believe `--ignore-directory` doesn't accept filters like `is:` like `--ignore-file` does. `--ignore-directory` accepts just a directory name.

Answer (score 3):

Also good to know with ack2.0, you can specify these options in a [`.ackrc` file](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/ack-2.04-man.html#the__ackrc_file) if you have to frequently filter files.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude specific folder, following command may help you:

`ack keywords --ignore-dir folder_name`

`man ack` will provide further details :)

> --[no]ignore-dir=DIRNAME, --[no]ignore-directory=DIRNAME
>
> --ignore-file=FILTERTYPE:FILTERARGS