# grep excluding file name pattern

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I've read
[Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files)
but in my CentOS6.4, when I do

```
grep --exclude=*.cmd ckim * -r
```

I see lots of grepped lines from *.cmd files.
so it seems the exclude option is not working for me.
What is wrong?
of course I can do things like

```
grep ckim \`find . -name \*.c -print\`
```

but I want to know why the grep doesn't work.

Comment: you need to include `pattern` parameter.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can quote the pattern:

```
grep -r --exclude="*.cmd"  "ckim" ./
```

PS. `./` is the current directory

Comment: This won't give a significant difference unless the OP has set `nullglob`. `--exclude=*.cmd` is unlikely to match a single file and would remain as is as an argument. It's the right practice but it doesn't give the solution.

Comment: @konsolebox, I must admit I don't know much about `nullglob` but `shopt` says it's `off` and still works. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should work but even if unquoted it still would. I might be wrong with my assumption actually, and that your code may actually be able to help solve the issue - not because you're helping it prevent itself from expanding to a file, but because you help prevent it from becoming nullified when `nullglob` is enabled. Thanks to quoting, any kind of pathname expansion is prevented. I can't believe I really overlooked that part.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.` as pathspec instead of `*`.

```
grep -r --exclude \*.cmd ckim .
```

Comment: On my test here the command still works even if `*` is used. Explicit file arguments are still filtered.

Comment: @konsolebox: ACK with Ubuntu

Comment: I think `.` with `-r` is more clear and never cause unwanted behaviour of shell-expansion.

Comment: @konsolebox: ACK with RHEL7

Answer (score 1):

you could also do something like this

```
grep -rn ckim * | grep -v '\.cmd'
```

Comment: This has unwanted behaviour, imagine the line inside the file has `something.cmd` it will not display that line even if the filename does not contain `\.cmd`

Comment: Yes it has some unwanted behavior ... but there will be very much less possibility of ckim occurring with  '.cmd' on the same line

Answer (score 1):

> I see lots of grepped lines from *.cmd files. So it seems **the exclude option is not working for me.**

There is a shell option called `nullglob` that controls the expansion of shell patterns when there is no matching file.

---

So, given the following environment:

```
sh$ touch f.cmd g.sh
sh$ mkdir sub
sh$ echo ckim > sub/h.cmd
sh$ echo ckim > sub/i.cmd
```

On **my** system (where `nullglob` is unset), the following command:

```
grep --exclude=*.cmd ckim * -r
```

Is expanded ("understood") by the shell as:

```
grep --exclude=*.cmd ckim f.cmd g.sh sub -r
```

That is, I will *recursively* (`-r`) search for the string `skim` starting with `f.cmd`, `g.sh` and `sub` but excluding any file matching the pattern '*.cmd'.

The result is:

```
# nullglob is unset
sh$ grep --exclude=*.cmd ckim * -r
sub/i.sh:ckim
```

**BUT** if in your environment the option `nullglob` is set, the same command expands to:

```
grep ckim f.cmd g.sh sub -r
```

Notice how the *whole* `--exclude=...` has disappeared. So the result is:

```
# nullglob is set
sh$ grep --exclude=*.cmd ckim * -r
sub/i.sh:ckim
sub/h.cmd:ckim
```

---

An now, for the explanation. When the shell encounters a *glob* pattern (i.e.: containing `*` or `?` or a few more special characters), it expands it with the matching files. *But* if there is no matching files, it either let the pattern as it (if `nullglob` is *not* set) or replace it with "nothing" (if `nullglob` is set).

Here the pattern is `--include=*.cmd` (at *whole* since there is no space in there). In the unlikely event you have a file matching this pattern it would have been replaced. Otherwise it is either let "as it" or completely removed -- depending on `nullglob`.

---

You can easely display, set (`-s`) or unset (`-u`) the status of `nullglob` option of your current bash:

```
sh$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        on

sh$ shopt -u nullglob
sh$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        off

sh$ shopt -s nullglob
sh$ shopt nullglob
nullglob        on
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest code for multiple files (note the DOT for files ending in '~') is:

```
grep -lr --exclude=*.{zip,bak,~} "Hello world!" world/* (wrong code)
grep -lr --exclude=*{zip,bak,~} "Hello world!" world/* (correct code)
```

ChatGPT can give you the wrong code for this specific case. The dot is not followed by '~', as in nycity.txt~

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude certain files to grep from, you should use the `-l` option.

```
grep -l --exclude=*.cmd ckim * -r
```