# Using grep to recursively search through subdirectories for specific keyword inside specific filename

Tags: linux, grep

Im trying to look for the text `Elapsed time` inside a specific log file names `vsim.log`. Im not familiar with grep, but after some googling I found that `grep -r` will allow me to do recursively searches and `grep -r "Elapsed time"` will do recursive searches for that phrase within all files in my directory. According to this link, I can then do `grep -r "Elapsed time" ./vsim*` to recursively search through the directories for files starting with `vsim` and look inside those files for `Elapsed time`. However, when i tried this i get `grep: No match.` which i know is not true since I know the files exist there with those keywords. What am i messing up?

Comment: Why not use the results of `find /path/to/search -type f -name "vsim.log"` to then search a single or a few files. It will be much faster.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Because I am not very familiar with Linux and am not really aware of the functionalities available as I am still learning. That being said, speed isnt too much of a factor at the moment but I will definitely read into find and probably learn to do it as you mentioned.

Comment: I provided an example as an answer. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The `*` is not interpreted by grep but by bash.  It performs path expansion.  This is in turn passed to grep.  Likely, nothing expanded in that directory is a directory so there's nothing for grep to recurse into.  As one commenter said to an answer, prefer to use `.` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you can use `find` to locate the file `vsim.log` if you do not know its exact location and then use the `-execdir` option to `find` to `grep` the file for the term `Elapsed time`, e.g.

```
find path -type f -name "vsim.log" -execdir grep -H 'Elapsed time' '{}' +
```

That will return the filename along with the matched text which you can simply parse to isolate the filename if desired. You can process all files that match if you anticipate more than one by feeding the results of the `find` command into a `while read -r` loop, e.g.

```
while read -r match; do
    # process "$match" as desired
    echo "Term 'Elapsed time' found in file ${match%:*}"
done < <(find path -type f -name "vsim.log" -execdir grep -H 'Elapsed time' '{}' +)
```

Where:

- `find` is the swiss-army knife for finding files on your system
- `path` can be any *relative* or *absolute* path to search (e.g. `$HOME` or `/home/dorojevets`) to search all files in your home directory
- the option `-type f` tells find to only locate files (see `man find` for link handling)
- the option `-name "foo"` tell find to only locate files named `foo` (wildcards allowed)
- the `-exec` and `-execdir` options allow you to execute the command that follows on each file (represented by `'{}'`)
- the `grep -H 'Elapsed time' '{}'` being the command to execute on each filename
- the `+` being what tells `find` it has reached the end of the command (`\;` used with `-exec`)
- finally, the `${match%:*}` *parameter expansion* on the variable `$match` is used to parse the *`filename`* from *`filename:Elapsed time`* returned by `grep -H` (the `%:*` simply being used to trim everything to the first `:` from the right of `$match`)

Give that a try and compare the execution time to a recursive `grep` of the file tree. What you may be missing in this discussion, is that you use `find` if you know some part of the filename (or *file mod time, or set of permissions, etc*) that contains the information you need. It can search millions of files in a file tree vastly quicker than you can recursively `grep` every single file. If you have no clue what file may contain the needed info -- then use `grep` and just wait...

Comment: Would this be in a file i execute or do i type the entire thing into the terminal ?

Comment: You can just type it into your terminal or include it in a script. Bash is wonderfully flexible. Anything you can do on the command line, you can put in a script and vice-versa... If used in a script, include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line to tell the interpreter to use `bash` and not some other shell. I updated the `while` loop to spit out the full path of the file containing any match of `Elapsed time` as an example.

Comment: I also removed `tmp` which is just the directory name I used to confirm the behavior. It is actually where you tell `find` to start searching, e.g. `find /path/to/search` (it will recursively search everything below that). It can be a *relative* or *absolute* path. If you run `find` on the entire root filesystem, include `-mount` option to prevent searching the `/dev`, `/proc`, and `/sys` system directories that can contain many things that are not files.

Comment: @dorojevets don't get me wrong, `find` can be a bit intimidating to make friends with. (especially when  you are just starting) But, it is one of those tools that is essential enough to everything you do on a Linux system, that you are well served to go ahead and learn it now. A good general reference is [**Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). It too should be your friend. Then use [**BashGuide - Greg's Wiki**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) to refine your use of bash.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
grep -r "Elapsed time" * --include vsim.log
```

Or this answer [Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files).

Comment: I would prefer `.` over `*` here (no chance of "command line too long", no chance of matching things that look like options to grep, no inconsistent skipping of hidden files on the top level only)

Answer (score 0):

The following works just in case if you are using Mac:

To search UUID in *.c files recursively under given folder "/home" use the following:

`grep -r "UUID" --include "*.c" /home/`

To recursively search UUID in all main.c files in multiple projects under current folder use the following:

`grep -r "UUID" --include "main.c" .`