# Recursive grep within specific subdirectories

Tags: bash, grep

I wish to grep certain files that only exist below a specific subdirectory. Here, I only want **.xml** files if they exist below the `/bar/` subdirectory:

```
./file0.xml
./.git/file1a.xml
./.git/bar/file1b.xml
./.svn/file2a.xml
./.svn/foo/bar/baz/file2b.xml
./path1/file3.xml
./path1/foo/file4.xml
./path2/foo/bar/file5.xml
./path2/foo/baz/file6.xml
./path3/bar/file7.xml
./path3/foo/bar/baz/file8.xml
```

I want only the following files to be grepped: `file5.xml`, `file7.xml`, `file8.xml`

[To exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files) `.git` and `.svn`, I came up with:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={.git,.svn} --include=\*.xml "pattern"
```

which still searches `file3.xml` through `file8.xml`.

If I `grep -v` the undesired directories:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={.git,.svn} --include=\*.xml "pattern" | grep -v /bar/
```

I get the desired results, but it spends a lot of time parsing the non-`/bar/` files.

Using `find` to find the xml files under `/res/`, I get the desired results (and it's much faster than the above result):

```
find . -type d \( -name .git -o -name .svn \) -prune -o \
       -path '*/bar/*.xml' -exec grep "pattern" {} +
```

I'm trying to avoid this, however, as I use this within a script and don't want to be limited to starting the search in the top `./` directory.

Is there a way to accomplish this using only grep (so it doesn't prevent the user from specifying additional grep options and/or starting search directories)? Perhaps something like:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={.git,.svn} --include=\*/bar/\*.xml "pattern"
```

Answer (score 1):

find+grep is definitely a good approach. You could make it more flexible by defining a function that inserts arguments in strategic places. For example:

```
search() {
    local dir=$1
    local pattern=$2
    local args=("${@:3}")

    find "$dir" -type d \( -name .git -o -name .svn \) -prune -o \
        -path '*/bar/*.xml' -exec grep "${args[@]}" "$pattern" {} +
}
```