# grep -r --include not works but --exclude works

Tags: linux, bash, grep, centos

In bash,

```
grep -r --exclude={*.c,} 'HELLO'  // exclude c files

grep -r --include={*.c,} 'HELLO'  // just same with grep -r 'HELLO'
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using curly braces incorrectly. The correct syntax would look like

```sh
grep -r --include='*.c' 'HELLO' .
```

(Notice also the addition of the missing file name argument `.` at the end.)

You can see what's going wrong by putting an `echo` in front and examining what the shell expands the braces to.

```
$ echo grep -r --exclude={*.c,} 'HELLO'
grep -r --exclude=*.c --exclude= HELLO
```

Comment: `GNU grep` will search current directory with `-r` active when filename argument isn't given

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of GNU conveniences which are not portable. I try to avoid them in answers when I can, or point out when something I use isn't portable, even when the question mentions a specific platform.

Comment: [The place where you apparently pioked up the braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221929/874188) has been updated to no longer recommend them.