Flag --include in grep does not accept numerous entries
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/221929/22132012
Why is it possible to use:
grep -rinHI --exclude={\*.h} pattern

And:
grep pattern -r --include=\*.cpp --include=\*.h rootdir

Both statements above print the expected results. But this command does not print anything:
grep -rinHI --include={\*.h,\*.cpp} pattern


Try grep -rinHI --include=\*.{h,cpp} pattern.
