# grep is not finding a pattern of \n and hyphens together (but can find them separately)

Tags: regex, grep, replace

I have some apt files that have code in them like this:

```
---

some code

---
```

Sometimes there's a blank line following the opening `---`, or before the closing `---`. I want to compress these (get rid of the unwanted "inside" blank lines). I'm quite willing to do so manually, but I'd like to print out a list of where all those are. I'm actually looking for `\n\n---\n\n`, but in the following I'll just show my work on `\n\n---`.

I've tried many variations on the following with no success:

```
grep -E \n\n---\n\n file.apt
```

Escaped the backslashes, tried \r, single and double quotes, grep --, w/o -E, ^$, etc. The following works:

```
grep \n\n file.apt
```

It prints all the right lines. The following also works:

```
grep "\---" file.apt
```

It prints all of the lines that have 3 hyphens. However, the following prints nothing:

```
grep "\n\n\---" file.apt
```

If I try that pattern `(\n\n---)` in vi I find what I'm looking for. All the failed grep attempts print nothing. So how can I find `"\n\n---"`?

I'm on Mac OSX, terminal command line.

Comment: Have you tired wrapping these queries in single qoutes so bash will interpret them literally?

Comment: Yeah, all combinations, even putting in a real return in the middle of the quoted regex. Same unwanted results.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that grep only matches a single line at a time. If you want to get rid of blank lines try running

```
grep ^$ -v file.apt
```

^$ will match every blank line and then the -v will print only lines that don't match.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get rid of only certain blank lines. I've tried one-line perl and sed, same result. My hunch is that I'm running into different flavors of regex and that I need one that just recognizes \n or \r as a return. I used TextWrangler's multi-file find with regex and it worked beautifully. One caveat to that solution: I had to open all the files I needed to change, as it would not open them itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a duplicate of: [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

There are good answers there that should help you. I'd probably use the `sed` option for what you are doing.