# RegEx to find NSLog, but not {\r.*NSLog

Tags: regex, xcode

In xCode I want to look for my NSLog statements that are not prefaced by a { from the previous line.

So I want to not find:

```
if (debug) {
    NSLog(@"MyDebug");
}
```

and only find.

```
  x=y+3;
  NSLog(@"MyDebug %d",x);
```

I was thinking something like : `(?<!\{\r.*NSLog).*NSLog`  or `(?<!\{)\r.*NSLog(?!\{)` though that does not seem to get me anything.

Comment: AFAIK, Xcode regexen cannot match across lines. You can add new lines in your replacement, but you can't match across lines in your pattern. Other tools are not so limited; perhaps try grep?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, multiline (`\n`) works as of 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeremy mentioned in the comments, Xcode doesn't support regexes that match multiple lines. However, according to [this message](http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2010-01/msg00268.html) in a thread on xcode-users, you can search for newline characters using non-regex search:

> Xcode's Find and Project Find don't support multiline regular
> expressions. They do support multiline text find...
>
> *(A [subsequent message](http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2010-01/msg00274.html) in the thread indicates that you can type a newline using <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd>.)*

If you know the line above the one you wish to match will always end with `;`, you could leverage that in a non-regex search.

As for grep, unfortunately it doesn't really like to [match multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep). pcregrep may be more useful.

Comment: Not Perfect as there are a variable number of spaces between the ; <CR> and NSLOG, but its much closer..  Thanks!