# search from end of line to next line

Tags: regex, vim, grep, special-characters, end-of-line

I am on Unix using gvim and grep.

#### Problem 1:

I need to search an xml file for the following pattern:

```
< sample1>
< /sample1>
```

So the problem is the pattern crosses a line. I am new to gvim and grep and could'nt figure this out using my regex/special characters knowledge.

#### Problem 2:

One additional problem is, there is white space before the less than sign (<) in the second line. i.e.

```
< sample1>
 < /sample1>
```

Could anyone please suggest how I can search for these patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search for this pattern in Vim use the `/` command in normal mode:

```
/< sample>\n< \/sample1>
```

Notice that the `/` character on the second line has to be escaped using the `\` character.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/< sample1>/,/< \/sample1>/p' file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

If you wish to exclude the separators:

```
sed -n '/< sample1>/,/< \/sample1>/ {//!p}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `< /sample1>` pattern just typing in command mode:

```
/< \/sample1>
```

I don't understand the second problem, since does not matter if there is a white space. Just put a white space after the search slash:

```
/ < \/sample1>
```

I've just tested this in Vim and it worked. Hope to be useful for you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

### ViM

You can use `\n` in ViM inside the search pattern.

#### Problem 1:

```
/<\ sample1>\n<\ \/sample1>
```

#### Problem 2:

```
/<\ sample1>\n\ <\ \/sample1>
```

If you want to be more precise and ignore cases like this:

```
blah blah < sample1>
 < /sample1> blah blah
```

You can explicitly ask to match the beginning and end of lines:

#### Problem 2:

```
/^<\ sample1>\n\ <\ \/sample1>$
```

If the amount of white space before the tags are not important, you can use `\s*`

```
/^\s*<\ sample1>\n\s*<\ \/sample1>$
```

### grep

If you are interested in using grep, I have bad news for you. grep doesn't do multiple lines. You can however look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686147/912144) and learn that `pcregrep -M` can solve your problem.