# Search for multiple patterns in a file not necessarily on the same line

Tags: unix, command

I need a unix command that would search multiple patterns (basically an AND), however those patterns need not be on the same line (otherwise I could use `grep` AND command). For e.g. suppose I have a file like following:

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
This is last line.
```

If I search for words 'first' and 'last', above file should be included in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this question, seems to be the same as yours with plenty of solutions: [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of AND you actually mean OR:

```
grep 'first\|last' file.txt
```

Results:

```
This is first line.
This is last line.
```

If you have a large number of patterns, add them to a file; for example if `patterns.txt` contains:

```
first
last
```

Run:

```
grep -f patterns.txt file.txt
```