# How to find the multiline pattern match (they must be first time match)?

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk

I know this question [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep) But I think my problem is more complicated. So I need help.

I have a dictionary file `BCFile` as

```
boundary
{
    inlet
    {
        type            fixedValue;
        value           uniform (5 0 0);
    }

    outlet
    {
        type            inletOutlet;
        inletValue      $internalField;
        value           $internalField;
    }

    ....
}
```

I am writing a script so to print out the `inlet` boundary condition `fixedValue`, and the `outlet` boundary condition `inletOutlet`.

If I use `cat BCFile | grep "type" | awk '{printf $2}'  | tr -d ";"`, it won't work as keyword `type` occurs many times.

If I use `awk -v RS='}' '/inlet/ { print $4 }' BCFile`, it won't work either, because keyword `inlet` also occurs many times.

I need a way to find pattern that first search for key word `inlet` and then search the **closest** `{` and `}`.

Anyone knows how to do it smartly?

Comment: look for awk solutions that have `flag` variables. Several appear here every week. ie. `'/type/{t=1};/value/{v=1}; {t && v}' file` (may not be exactly right, hence posted as a comment). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide expected output for the input you posted we're just guessing at what you want output but how about this in GNU awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ RS="\0" }
{
   print "inlet:",  gensub(/.*\yinlet\y[^}]*type\s+(\w+).*/,"\\1","")
   print "outlet:", gensub(/.*\youtlet\y[^}]*type\s+(\w+).*/,"\\1","")
}
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
inlet: fixedValue
outlet: inletOutlet
```

Explanation:

```
RS="\0"
```

= set the Record Separator to the Null string so awk reads the whole file as a single record.

```
gensub(/.*\yinlet\y[^}]*type\s+(\w+).*/,"\\1","")
```

= look for the word `inlet` followed by any characters except a `}` (so you stop before the first `}` after `inlet` instead of the last `}` in the file) and then the word `type` followed by white space. The alpha-numeric string after that (`\w+`) is the word you want printed so remember it and then replace the whole record with just that string as saved in `\\1`.

Setting `RS="\0"` and `gensub()` are both gawk-specific.

Comment: Wow, my hat's off. Would you please add a few explanations to the syntax? :)

Comment: @Daniel - explanations added. See also the gawk manual, http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html. If you're going to be doing text file manipulation like this, I'd strongly recommend you get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to scripting, I have a big difficulty in choosing between `sed` and `awk`? Which is more powerful or more flexible or has a good and rewarding learning  curve? Thanks

Comment: Like all UNIX tools, you should use both tools as appropriate. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text manipulation you should use awk. You can do a LOT of things in sed that you should NEVER do - that's because sed predated awk by a few years so it has a ton of language constructs to do things in ridiculously complicated ways just because back in the day (early 1970s!) there was no simpler alternative. The only commands you should use in sed are s, g, p (with -n), and d.

Comment: By the way, being completely honest - best I can tell the reason experienced people still post sed solutions using more than those 4 constructs is because they simply enjoy the challenge of solving the problem with sed. I get that, kinda, but I wish they wouldn't as it misleads newcomers into thinking that's a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use perl?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];

open(my $f, '<', $filename) or die "Unable to open $filename: $!\n";
my $string = do { local($/); <$f> };
close($f);

$string =~ /(inlet).*type\s*(\w+).*(outlet).*type\s*(\w+)/s;
print "$1: $2\n$3: $4\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but no shell scripts can do this?

Comment: UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools. perl is a tool just like sed, grep, awk, etc. The only difference is that unlike the other tools I mentioned, perl doesn't come with all UNIX installations.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^\s*(inlet|outlet)/,/^\s*}/!b;/type/s/.*\s(\S+);.*/\1/p' file
```

If you narrow the search for 'type' between either 'inlet' and the next '}' or 'outlet' and the next '}' this makes the whole exercise easier.