# Why using variable in awk printf doesn't work?

Tags: shell, awk

Newbie here. I am trying to use awk print a few information. So I wrote a shell scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

turbVar="U"
bcName="outlet"
str="$turbVar $bcName b.c. = "
# method-1
awk -v RS='}' '/'$bcName'/ { printf "%20s = %s\n" $str $4; exit;}' BCFile  | tr -d ";"
# method-2
awk -v RS='}' -v var1=$bcName '$0 ~ var1 { printf "%20s = %s\n" $str $4; exit;}' BCFile  | tr -d ";"
```

The `BCFile` file contents are

```
boundary
{
    inlet
    {
        type            fixedValue;
        value           uniform (5 0 0);
    }

    outlet
    {
        type            inletOutlet;
        inletValue      $internalField;
        value           $internalField;
    }

    ....
}
```

I hope to output something like

```
U outlet b.c. = inletOutlet
```

Sadly, this does not work. it complains `awk: (FILENAME=0/U FNR=4) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string %20s = %s`.

Why I can't use $str variable in awk printf?

Second question, which method is better? Using `'/'$bcName'/` or using `-v var1=$bcName '$0 ~ var1`?, why I cant use `'/$bcName/` or `'/"$bcName"/`directly? What is the difference between strong quote and weak quote here?

Comment: What is `0/U` suppose to be?

Comment: It is a file. Its content is shown in this post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825150/how-to-find-the-multiline-pattern-match-they-must-be-first-time-match`

Comment: The file `U` is in a folder called `0`. :)

Comment: @sudo_O - FYI you cannot name a file with a forward slash in it. Ditto for a nul character '\0'.

Comment: @Daniel - wrt your question of `What is the difference between strong quote and weak quote`. What do you consider a "strong" vs 'weak" quote? We normally just talk about single and double quotes. In the case of your script just don't do any of the alternatives referred to in your question - they are both very bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code cleaned up should be:

```
awk -v RS="}" -v v1="$bcName" -v s="$str" '$0~v1{gsub(/;/,"");printf "%s%s\n",s,$4;exit}' 
U outlet b.c. = inletOutlet
```

Notes:

- Don't play with shell expansion and quoting it's a real headache. Pass in any shell variables nicely with `-v`.
- You need to comma separator the arguments to `printf`.
- Always quote your shell variables!
- You should being doing `gsub(/;/,"")` inside the `awk` script instead of `tr -d ";"`.

However it may not be the best approach but I couldn't say as no context was provied.

Comment: No, it's not working. The output is messed up since there are many key word `outlet` in the file. :(

Comment: That is because you want `$str` to be expanded from the shell -- which sudo_O probably missed... but the solution is in his answer: pass the value in with `-v str="$str"`

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke good spot missed that one, answer needs reworking anyway due to the new information given by OP.

Comment: LOL, @sudo_O, would you please also teach me how to add `gsub` in my case? So I dont need `tr` anymore. Thanks

Comment: Btw, I am also surprised, since in shell no comma is needed for printf, but I have to use comman in awk.

Comment: @Daniel - awk is not shell, just like C is not shell, Ada is not shell, etc. awk is it's own tool with it's own syntax which just bears some similarity to shell and C thanks to all 3 having been invented by the same company.