# egrep : regular expression in between start and end

Tags: regex, grep

i have following code:

```
egrep -v "(^/\*\!40101.*\*/;$|^/\*\!50001.*\*/;$)"
```

that will working fine to skip text like this:

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
/*!50001 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `some_table_name`*/;
```

however if i have text like this:

```
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `some_table_name` (
  `id` int(11),
  `field1` char(30),
  `field2` char(30),
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
```

it failed to skip it. Any idea?

**What i want is:**

if there is a text

```
Start with : /*!40101
End with : */;
```

or

if there is a text

```
Start with : /*!50001
End with : */;
```

I want to skip whole line, or whole block of it. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? its mysqldump, mysql uses these special comments for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex skips everything that starts 40101 or 50001 up to the end of the line but not onto the next line.  It doesn't look like egrep supports multiline matching.

Comment: added addition info to the question.

Comment: it looks like the pattern needs to match before the end of line.

Comment: how to do that? i only able to match them if they are in 1 line, how to do to match for few line

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)