# Select lines between known line and line with first-matched sign at the end

Tags: shell, sed, awk, sh

There is the file with below content (file.conf):

```
/etc/:
rc.conf
passwd
/usr/:
/usr/local/etc/:
```

I need select lines between "/etc/:" and first-matching lines with ":" at the end.

```
cat ./file.conf | sed -n '/\/etc\/:/,/\/.*:$/p'
```

prints all content but I need

```
/etc/:
rc.conf
passwd
/usr/:
```

With this command `cat ./file.conf | sed -n '/\/etc\/:/,/\/.*:$/p; :q'` the same.

Comment: cat is useless : `sed -n '/\/etc\/:/,/\/.*:$/p' file.conf`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy a section within two keywords into a target file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434755/copy-a-section-within-two-keywords-into-a-target-file)

Comment: No. This is not duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution

```
awk '/^\/etc\// {f=1} f; /:$/ && !/\/etc\//{f=0}' file.conf
/etc/:
rc.conf
passwd
/usr/:
```

---

another version

```
awk '/^\/etc\// {f=1;print;next} f; /:$/ {f=0}' file.conf

awk '
    /^\/etc\// {    # search for /etc/, if found do
        f=1         # set flag f=1
        print       # print this line (/etc/ line)
        next        # skip to next line so this would not be printed twice
        } 
    f;              # Is flag f set, yes do default action { print $0 }
    /:$/ {          # does line end with : 
        f=0         # yes, reset flag
        }
    ' file.conf
```

Comment: Yes, it's works. Thanks! But just for me, is it possible with sed? May be something like :{2}q in the last sed command...

Comment: It certainly is possible with ``sed``. You might have to make use of conditional branching.

Comment: Solution with awk is suitable for me, but need some help. What is means "{f=1;print;next} f" in last command?

Comment: See may updated info.  If you like my answer, give it some cred :)

Comment: @Jotne Yes. Your answer is great! But I dont know how I can add you credits? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/\/etc\/:/{:loop; $q; $!N; /:/b p; b loop; }; :p; p' file.conf
```

**Output:**

```
/etc/:
rc.conf
passwd
/usr/:
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu, this give me the unwanted last line. `/usr/local/etc/:`

Comment: Now it seems to be ok :)

Comment: on my FreeBSD  sed: 1: "/\/etc\/:/{:loop; $q; $ ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: @Andry, Try this: `sed -n '/\/etc\/:/{:loop; N; /:$/b p; b loop;}; :p; p' file.conf`