# Eclipse file search pattern for exactly two occurences

Tags: eclipse

I want to run file search over files like the guy shown [here](http://jgeeks.blogspot.com/2013/10/searching-multiple-words-in-multiple.html).
I want to find the files containing **string1 and string2** . Not string1 or string2. 
And most importantly the strings can be on different lines.
I searched SO for it but I only found it with or clause and the regex is for the same line. Can you help me?

What I am looking for is some [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep).

However I am using windows and my options are limited. Can I achieve this on eclipse?

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't really make much sense. Could you provide a real life example? Why note just use `grep` / external tool? Is it a feature you want to implement, or a feature you need?

Comment: http://jgeeks.blogspot.com/2013/10/searching-multiple-words-in-multiple.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Go to `File Search` tab select/check the **"Regullar Expression"** button and in the **Containing text** text box, use the blow regular expression

`(?m)(?s).*(string1).*(string2).*` --> Searches string1 first then string2.

If you want string2 to be searched first then use `(?m)(?s).*(string2).*(string1).*`.

To know about (?m) and (?s) [go here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)