# multiline regular expression help in eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need a regular expression for eclipse that finds the string XYZ if it's somewhere in the `<formula>` tags. it is certainly across multiple lines too.

If easier, i can do this in notepad++

```
<formula>
    potential stuff. could be in tags
    XYZ 
    potential stuff. could be in tags
</formula>
```

Comment: the regular expression finder in eclipse or notepad++

Comment: what you want to do with `XYZ`? Do you want to replace it with someone else.

Comment: no, i need to do a manual process with it.

Comment: `<formula>[^<]*XYZ[^<]*</formula>` will highlight any formula block which includes XYZ.  Did you want that or just `XYZ` highlighted?  NOTE: Could only test in MyEclipse for Spring, not Eclipse (don't know which version of Eclipse you're using anyway).

Answer (score -1):

Use : `(?m)(?s)<formula>.*(XYZ).*</formula>`

Refer [Eclipse File Search Dialog - Regular Expression for Group Unions and Negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577308/eclipse-file-search-dialog-regular-expression-for-group-unions-and-negation)
and
[Eclipse file search pattern for exactly two occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952554/eclipse-file-search-pattern-for-exactly-two-occurences/20966525#20966525)