# Regex to search a specific text between two tags using Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I need to find the occurrence of some specific text inside a cfquery tag using cfeclipse regex search. Can any one help me writing the regex?

```
<cfset address = Trim(arguments.address) />
<cfquery datasource="testDataSource">
SELECT * FROM TEST
WHERE name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Trim(arguments.name)#"  />
</cfquery>
```

In the above code if I do a search for Trim, It should return the Trim inside the cfquery tag alone.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can put a sample data about what you have and what you need?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
(?m)(?s)<cfquery(.*?)(Trim)(.*?)/(cfquery)?>
```

Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24879276/1391924 and this [Regular expression to stop at first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503413/regular-expression-to-stop-at-first-match)

---

Note: Add **(?i)** if you need case insensitive search.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution helps me but if I have more than 1 <cfquery blocks in a single file and only one contains the Trim text, When I do the search, it highlights the whole file from first <cfquery start tag to last </cfquery> end tag. Is there any way to highlight only the <cfquery block which contain Trim??

Comment: corrected my answer please check

Comment: Further corrected my answer, combined two regex into one