# Linux script for matching a multi-line statement

Tags: linux, shell, sed, zsh, multiline

How can I write a fast shell script to match the following in linux. I have tried various combinations of grep commands, sed commands but no success. The "message" section can be repeated any number of times. The contents of the "message" itself will be generic but fixed to the format shown below. I want the output to be something like:

```
x: y
x1: y1
x: y
x1: y1
x: y
x1: y1
```

Input:

```
Posting to abcd
message {
 a {
     x : y
     x1 : y1
   }
}
message {
 a {
     x : y
     x1 : y1
   }
}
message {
 a {
     x : y
     x1 : y1
   }
}
```

Comment: Check out pcregrep as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2686705/2413778) answer.

Comment: what to match exactly a section starting with Posting followed by 3 message section with a single section of a that contain exactly x : y and x1 : y1 value ? or a bit more generic with more or less section/sub section and variable name + value each of different content like string/number/other ? And this in a huge file with several occurence ?

Comment: Ya the "message" section can be repeated any number of times. The contents of the message itself will be generic but fixed to the format shown above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing json with sed and awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-sed-and-awk)

Comment: Can you give a better description of what you want, this command `awk '/^    /' inputfile` will give the output you suggested given the input file but im almost sure it wont work for what you actually want.

Comment: As I understand it, I would propose `sed -n 's/^ *\([^ :]\+\) *: *\([^ :]\+\)/\1: \2/p' inputfile` but indeed the question isn't clear. Moreover the user may also want to validate the input file and output an error if the format is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^message {/,/^}/{/[{}]/d;s/^\s*//}' file
```

Within the block `message {` to `}`, delete any lines containing a `{` or a `}` and then remove any white space from the start of any subsequent line.