# pipe tcpdump output to grep multiline pattern

Tags: grep, pipe, multiline, tcpdump

I want to grep a multiline pattern from tcpdump output like the following:
sudo tcpdump -A -s0 | grep -Pzo 'foo.*\n.*bar'
However, it does not seem to work. But it works if I dump the data into a file and then grep the file. How can I make the command using pipe working?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `-l`:

> ```
> -l     Make stdout line buffered.  Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it.
>        E.g.,
>             tcpdump -l | tee dat
>             tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat
> ```

Comment: Tried sudo tcpdump -A -s0 -l | grep -Pzo 'foo.*\n.*bar'

Comment: but it still does not work. I found the problem might be caused by the -z option of grep. When that is set, even sudo tcpdump -A -s0 | grep -Pzo foo will not work.

Comment: grep '' was not working for me. The -l switch cured it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't get why the grep does not work above even with -l option for tcpdump, but I found this stackoverflow post [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep). So I tried pcregrep, and it worked.
sudo tcpdump -A -s0 | pcregrep -Mo "foo.*\n.*bar"

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems piping the output to tail even with the -l switch as well. I was able to solve my problem by using `multitail` instead of `tail -F`.

This worked for me:  `multitail -l "tcpdump -li eth0"`