# Grep multiline regex

Tags: regex, grep

consider the following

```
[Settings]
Flags=17
InHouse=0
PrintMode=4
version=3.0
Background Color=16051165
AutoSaveMin=900000
DefaultTemplate=Untitled.ipt
Save template=1
```

I'm using `grep` to loop through thousands of ini files to look for the following:

```
version=3.0
```

AND

```
DefaultTemplate=[alphanumeric]
```

below does not return any results, what am I missing?

**version=3.0[\s\S]*DefaultTemplate=[A-Za-z0-9]**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

Comment: As a regex it appears ok. Is it a grep question? You should use the layz quantifier version though `version=3.0[\s\S]*?DefaultTemplate=[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -P '(DefaultTemplate=[\w\.]+|version=[\d\.]+)' *
```

Comment: Almost, it acts like an OR instead of AND

Comment: ? I get the 2 lines, I don't get you.

Comment: nvm, yours is close enough, i can work with that, thanks