# Multiple line, repeated occurence matching

Tags: regex, sed, grep, cygwin

I refer to below question, but with a bit difference. I need to only get line that has "abc" when there is "efg" matching at different line. And I only need the latest matched "abc" line before "efg" is matched...

[How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

```
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah1
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah2
blah blah..
blah efg1 blah blah
blah efg2 blah blah
blah blah..
blah blah..

blah abc blah3
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah4
blah blah..
blah blah blah

blah abc blah5
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah6
blah blah..
blah efg3 blah blah

blah efg4 blah blah
blah abc blah7
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah8
blah blah..
```

Expected output

```
blah abc blah2
blah abc blah6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/abc/h;/efg/!b;x;/abc/p;z;x' file
```

Store the latest `abc` line in the hold space (HS). When encountering a line containing `efg`, switch to the HS and if that line contains `abc` print it.

Comment: trying to understand the syntax, https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html but couldnt figure out "/!b", could you please explain a bit?

Comment: @user3663854  the address can be negated by appending `!` and the `b` command is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands).

Answer (score 0):

I can see how to do this in two steps, one to identify the blocks of `abc` ... `efg` clusters, but with multiple of the former. Second step is to strip down to the two lines that matter.

Important: make sure there are no pairs of empty lines in the input `\n\n`, as that will break the perl step.

```
grep -Pzo '(.*abc.*)\n(.*\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)' text | perl -0777 -pe 's/(.+\n)*(.*abc.*\n)(.+\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)\n/$2$4/g'
```

For example:

```
grep -Pzo '(.*abc.*)\n(.*\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)' text
blah abc blah1
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah2
blah blah..
blah efg1 blah blah

blah abc blah3
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah4
blah blah..
blah blah blah
blah abc blah5
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah abc blah6
blah blah..
blah efg3 blah blah
```

See how the `efg` chunks are separated by two newlines? We then remove the cruft that doesn't matter with a perl search-and-replace regex:

```
$ grep -Pzo '(.*abc.*)\n(.*\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)' text | perl -0777 -pe 's/(.+\n)*(.*abc.*\n)(.+\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)\n/$2$4/g'
blah abc blah2
blah efg1 blah blah
blah abc blah6
blah efg3 blah blah
```

If you just want the `abc` line, just include `$2` in the replace block (remove `$4`).

```
$ grep -Pzo '(.*abc.*)\n(.*\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)' text | perl -0777 -pe 's/(.+\n)*(.*abc.*\n)(.+\n)*?(.*efg.*\n)\n/$2/g'
blah abc blah2
blah abc blah6
```