# bash: Regular expression to get just single paragraph?

Tags: regex, string, bash, text, grep

I am working with the following text:

```
>HSBGPG Human gene for bone gla protein (BGP)
GGCAGATTCCCCCTAGACCCGCCCGCACCATGGTCAGGCATGCCCCTCCTCATCGCTGGGCACAGCCCAGAGGGT
ATAAACAGTGCTGGAGGCTGGCGGGGCAGGCCAGCTGAGTCCTGAGCAGCAGCCCAGCGCAGCCACCGAGACACC
ATGAGAGCCCTCACACTCCTCGCCCTATTGGCCCTGGCCGCACTTTGCATCGCTGGCCAGGCAGGTGAGTGCCCC
CACCTCCCCTCAGGCCGCATTGCAGTGGGGGCTGAGAGGAGGAAGCACCATGGCCCACCTCTTCTCACCCCTTTG
GCTGGCAGTCCCTTTGCAGTCTAACCACCTTGTTGCAGGCTCAATCCATTTGCCCCAGCTCTGCCCTTGCAGAGG
GAGAGGAGGGAAGAGCAAGCTGCCCGAGACGCAGGGGAAGGAGGATGAGGGCCCTGGGGATGAGCTGGGGTGAAC
CAGGCTCCCTTTCCTTTGCAGGTGCGAAGCCCAGCGGTGCAGAGTCCAGCAAAGGTGCAGGTATGAGGATGGACC
TGATGGGTTCCTGGACCCTCCCCTCTCACCCTGGTCCCTCAGTCTCATTCCCCCACTCCTGCCACCTCCTGTCTG
GCCATCAGGAAGGCCAGCCTGCTCCCCACCTGATCCTCCCAAACCCAGAGCCACCTGATGCCTGCCCCTCTGCTC
CACAGCCTTTGTGTCCAAGCAGGAGGGCAGCGAGGTAGTGAAGAGACCCAGGCGCTACCTGTATCAATGGCTGGG
GTGAGAGAAAAGGCAGAGCTGGGCCAAGGCCCTGCCTCTCCGGGATGGTCTGTGGGGGAGCTGCAGCAGGGAGTG
GCCTCTCTGGGTTGTGGTGGGGGTACAGGCAGCCTGCCCTGGTGGGCACCCTGGAGCCCCATGTGTAGGGAGAGG
AGGGATGGGCATTTTGCACGGGGGCTGATGCCACCACGTCGGGTGTCTCAGAGCCCCAGTCCCCTACCCGGATCC
CCTGGAGCCCAGGAGGGAGGTGTGTGAGCTCAATCCGGACTGTGACGAGTTGGCTGACCACATCGGCTTTCAGGA
GGCCTATCGGCGCTTCTACGGCCCGGTCTAGGGTGTCGCTCTGCTGGCCTGGCCGGCAACCCCAGTTCTGCTCCT
CTCCAGGCACCCTTCTTTCCTCTTCCCCTTGCCCTTGCCCTGACCTCCCAGCCCTATGGATGTGGGGTCCCCATC
ATCCCAGCTGCTCCCAAATAAACTCCAGAAG
>HSGLTH1 Human theta 1-globin gene
CCACTGCACTCACCGCACCCGGCCAATTTTTGTGTTTTTAGTAGAGACTAAATACCATATAGTGAACACCTAAGA
CGGGGGGCCTTGGATCCAGGGCGATTCAGAGGGCCCCGGTCGGAGCTGTCGGAGATTGAGCGCGCGCGGTCCCGG
GATCTCCGACGAGGCCCTGGACCCCCGGGCGGCGAAGCTGCGGCGCGGCGCCCCCTGGAGGCCGCGGGACCCCTG
GCCGGTCCGCGCAGGCGCAGCGGGGTCGCAGGGCGCGGCGGGTTCCAGCGCGGGGATGGCGCTGTCCGCGGAGGA
CCGGGCGCTGGTGCGCGCCCTGTGGAAGAAGCTGGGCAGCAACGTCGGCGTCTACACGACAGAGGCCCTGGAAAG
GTGCGGCAGGCTGGGCGCCCCCGCCCCCAGGGGCCCTCCCTCCCCAAGCCCCCCGGACGCGCCTCACCCACGTTC
CTCTCGCAGGACCTTCCTGGCTTTCCCCGCCACGAAGACCTACTTCTCCCACCTGGACCTGAGCCCCGGCTCCTC
ACAAGTCAGAGCCCACGGCCAGAAGGTGGCGGACGCGCTGAGCCTCGCCGTGGAGCGCCTGGACGACCTACCCCA
CGCGCTGTCCGCGCTGAGCCACCTGCACGCGTGCCAGCTGCGAGTGGACCCGGCCAGCTTCCAGGTGAGCGGCTG
CCGTGCTGGGCCCCTGTCCCCGGGAGGGCCCCGGCGGGGTGGGTGCGGGGGGCGTGCGGGGCGGGTGCAGGCGAG
TGAGCCTTGAGCGCTCGCCGCAGCTCCTGGGCCACTGCCTGCTGGTAACCCTCGCCCGGCACTACCCCGGAGACT
TCAGCCCCGCGCTGCAGGCGTCGCTGGACAAGTTCCTGAGCCACGTTATCTCGGCGCTGGTTTCCGAGTACCGCT
GAACTGTGGGTGGGTGGCCGCGGGATCCCCAGGCGACCTTCCCCGTGTTTGAGTAAAGCCTCTCCCAGGAGCAGC
CTTCTTGCCGTGCTCTCTCGAGGTCAGGACGCGAGAGGAAGGCGC
```

I would like to get the individuals sequences. Match #1 should be:

```
   GGCAGATTCCCCCTAGACCCGCCCGCACCATGGTCAGGCATGCCCCTCCTCATCGCTGGGCACAGCCCAGAGGGT
    ATAAACAGTGCTGGAGGCTGGCGGGGCAGGCCAGCTGAGTCCTGAGCAGCAGCCCAGCGCAGCCACCGAGACACC
    ATGAGAGCCCTCACACTCCTCGCCCTATTGGCCCTGGCCGCACTTTGCATCGCTGGCCAGGCAGGTGAGTGCCCC
    CACCTCCCCTCAGGCCGCATTGCAGTGGGGGCTGAGAGGAGGAAGCACCATGGCCCACCTCTTCTCACCCCTTTG
    GCTGGCAGTCCCTTTGCAGTCTAACCACCTTGTTGCAGGCTCAATCCATTTGCCCCAGCTCTGCCCTTGCAGAGG
    GAGAGGAGGGAAGAGCAAGCTGCCCGAGACGCAGGGGAAGGAGGATGAGGGCCCTGGGGATGAGCTGGGGTGAAC
    CAGGCTCCCTTTCCTTTGCAGGTGCGAAGCCCAGCGGTGCAGAGTCCAGCAAAGGTGCAGGTATGAGGATGGACC
    TGATGGGTTCCTGGACCCTCCCCTCTCACCCTGGTCCCTCAGTCTCATTCCCCCACTCCTGCCACCTCCTGTCTG
    GCCATCAGGAAGGCCAGCCTGCTCCCCACCTGATCCTCCCAAACCCAGAGCCACCTGATGCCTGCCCCTCTGCTC
    CACAGCCTTTGTGTCCAAGCAGGAGGGCAGCGAGGTAGTGAAGAGACCCAGGCGCTACCTGTATCAATGGCTGGG
    GTGAGAGAAAAGGCAGAGCTGGGCCAAGGCCCTGCCTCTCCGGGATGGTCTGTGGGGGAGCTGCAGCAGGGAGTG
    GCCTCTCTGGGTTGTGGTGGGGGTACAGGCAGCCTGCCCTGGTGGGCACCCTGGAGCCCCATGTGTAGGGAGAGG
    AGGGATGGGCATTTTGCACGGGGGCTGATGCCACCACGTCGGGTGTCTCAGAGCCCCAGTCCCCTACCCGGATCC
    CCTGGAGCCCAGGAGGGAGGTGTGTGAGCTCAATCCGGACTGTGACGAGTTGGCTGACCACATCGGCTTTCAGGA
    GGCCTATCGGCGCTTCTACGGCCCGGTCTAGGGTGTCGCTCTGCTGGCCTGGCCGGCAACCCCAGTTCTGCTCCT
    CTCCAGGCACCCTTCTTTCCTCTTCCCCTTGCCCTTGCCCTGACCTCCCAGCCCTATGGATGTGGGGTCCCCATC
    ATCCCAGCTGCTCCCAAATAAACTCCAGAAG
```

and match #2 should be:

```
CCACTGCACTCACCGCACCCGGCCAATTTTTGTGTTTTTAGTAGAGACTAAATACCATATAGTGAACACCTAAGA
    CGGGGGGCCTTGGATCCAGGGCGATTCAGAGGGCCCCGGTCGGAGCTGTCGGAGATTGAGCGCGCGCGGTCCCGG
    GATCTCCGACGAGGCCCTGGACCCCCGGGCGGCGAAGCTGCGGCGCGGCGCCCCCTGGAGGCCGCGGGACCCCTG
    GCCGGTCCGCGCAGGCGCAGCGGGGTCGCAGGGCGCGGCGGGTTCCAGCGCGGGGATGGCGCTGTCCGCGGAGGA
    CCGGGCGCTGGTGCGCGCCCTGTGGAAGAAGCTGGGCAGCAACGTCGGCGTCTACACGACAGAGGCCCTGGAAAG
    GTGCGGCAGGCTGGGCGCCCCCGCCCCCAGGGGCCCTCCCTCCCCAAGCCCCCCGGACGCGCCTCACCCACGTTC
    CTCTCGCAGGACCTTCCTGGCTTTCCCCGCCACGAAGACCTACTTCTCCCACCTGGACCTGAGCCCCGGCTCCTC
    ACAAGTCAGAGCCCACGGCCAGAAGGTGGCGGACGCGCTGAGCCTCGCCGTGGAGCGCCTGGACGACCTACCCCA
    CGCGCTGTCCGCGCTGAGCCACCTGCACGCGTGCCAGCTGCGAGTGGACCCGGCCAGCTTCCAGGTGAGCGGCTG
    CCGTGCTGGGCCCCTGTCCCCGGGAGGGCCCCGGCGGGGTGGGTGCGGGGGGCGTGCGGGGCGGGTGCAGGCGAG
    TGAGCCTTGAGCGCTCGCCGCAGCTCCTGGGCCACTGCCTGCTGGTAACCCTCGCCCGGCACTACCCCGGAGACT
    TCAGCCCCGCGCTGCAGGCGTCGCTGGACAAGTTCCTGAGCCACGTTATCTCGGCGCTGGTTTCCGAGTACCGCT
    GAACTGTGGGTGGGTGGCCGCGGGATCCCCAGGCGACCTTCCCCGTGTTTGAGTAAAGCCTCTCCCAGGAGCAGC
    CTTCTTGCCGTGCTCTCTCGAGGTCAGGACGCGAGAGGAAGGCGC
```

This is basically same thing excluding the lines starting with the '>' character. So far, I tried:

```
grep '^[^>].*'
```

This returns both sequences as a block:

```
GGCAGATTCCCCCTAGACCCGCCCGCACCATGGTCAGGCATGCCCCTCCTCATCGCTGGGCACAGCCCAGAGGGT
ATAAACAGTGCTGGAGGCTGGCGGGGCAGGCCAGCTGAGTCCTGAGCAGCAGCCCAGCGCAGCCACCGAGACACC
ATGAGAGCCCTCACACTCCTCGCCCTATTGGCCCTGGCCGCACTTTGCATCGCTGGCCAGGCAGGTGAGTGCCCC
CACCTCCCCTCAGGCCGCATTGCAGTGGGGGCTGAGAGGAGGAAGCACCATGGCCCACCTCTTCTCACCCCTTTG
GCTGGCAGTCCCTTTGCAGTCTAACCACCTTGTTGCAGGCTCAATCCATTTGCCCCAGCTCTGCCCTTGCAGAGG
GAGAGGAGGGAAGAGCAAGCTGCCCGAGACGCAGGGGAAGGAGGATGAGGGCCCTGGGGATGAGCTGGGGTGAAC
CAGGCTCCCTTTCCTTTGCAGGTGCGAAGCCCAGCGGTGCAGAGTCCAGCAAAGGTGCAGGTATGAGGATGGACC
TGATGGGTTCCTGGACCCTCCCCTCTCACCCTGGTCCCTCAGTCTCATTCCCCCACTCCTGCCACCTCCTGTCTG
GCCATCAGGAAGGCCAGCCTGCTCCCCACCTGATCCTCCCAAACCCAGAGCCACCTGATGCCTGCCCCTCTGCTC
CACAGCCTTTGTGTCCAAGCAGGAGGGCAGCGAGGTAGTGAAGAGACCCAGGCGCTACCTGTATCAATGGCTGGG
GTGAGAGAAAAGGCAGAGCTGGGCCAAGGCCCTGCCTCTCCGGGATGGTCTGTGGGGGAGCTGCAGCAGGGAGTG
GCCTCTCTGGGTTGTGGTGGGGGTACAGGCAGCCTGCCCTGGTGGGCACCCTGGAGCCCCATGTGTAGGGAGAGG
AGGGATGGGCATTTTGCACGGGGGCTGATGCCACCACGTCGGGTGTCTCAGAGCCCCAGTCCCCTACCCGGATCC
CCTGGAGCCCAGGAGGGAGGTGTGTGAGCTCAATCCGGACTGTGACGAGTTGGCTGACCACATCGGCTTTCAGGA
GGCCTATCGGCGCTTCTACGGCCCGGTCTAGGGTGTCGCTCTGCTGGCCTGGCCGGCAACCCCAGTTCTGCTCCT
CTCCAGGCACCCTTCTTTCCTCTTCCCCTTGCCCTTGCCCTGACCTCCCAGCCCTATGGATGTGGGGTCCCCATC
ATCCCAGCTGCTCCCAAATAAACTCCAGAAG
CCACTGCACTCACCGCACCCGGCCAATTTTTGTGTTTTTAGTAGAGACTAAATACCATATAGTGAACACCTAAGA
CGGGGGGCCTTGGATCCAGGGCGATTCAGAGGGCCCCGGTCGGAGCTGTCGGAGATTGAGCGCGCGCGGTCCCGG
GATCTCCGACGAGGCCCTGGACCCCCGGGCGGCGAAGCTGCGGCGCGGCGCCCCCTGGAGGCCGCGGGACCCCTG
GCCGGTCCGCGCAGGCGCAGCGGGGTCGCAGGGCGCGGCGGGTTCCAGCGCGGGGATGGCGCTGTCCGCGGAGGA
CCGGGCGCTGGTGCGCGCCCTGTGGAAGAAGCTGGGCAGCAACGTCGGCGTCTACACGACAGAGGCCCTGGAAAG
GTGCGGCAGGCTGGGCGCCCCCGCCCCCAGGGGCCCTCCCTCCCCAAGCCCCCCGGACGCGCCTCACCCACGTTC
CTCTCGCAGGACCTTCCTGGCTTTCCCCGCCACGAAGACCTACTTCTCCCACCTGGACCTGAGCCCCGGCTCCTC
ACAAGTCAGAGCCCACGGCCAGAAGGTGGCGGACGCGCTGAGCCTCGCCGTGGAGCGCCTGGACGACCTACCCCA
CGCGCTGTCCGCGCTGAGCCACCTGCACGCGTGCCAGCTGCGAGTGGACCCGGCCAGCTTCCAGGTGAGCGGCTG
CCGTGCTGGGCCCCTGTCCCCGGGAGGGCCCCGGCGGGGTGGGTGCGGGGGGCGTGCGGGGCGGGTGCAGGCGAG
TGAGCCTTGAGCGCTCGCCGCAGCTCCTGGGCCACTGCCTGCTGGTAACCCTCGCCCGGCACTACCCCGGAGACT
TCAGCCCCGCGCTGCAGGCGTCGCTGGACAAGTTCCTGAGCCACGTTATCTCGGCGCTGGTTTCCGAGTACCGCT
GAACTGTGGGTGGGTGGCCGCGGGATCCCCAGGCGACCTTCCCCGTGTTTGAGTAAAGCCTCTCCCAGGAGCAGC
CTTCTTGCCGTGCTCTCTCGAGGTCAGGACGCGAGAGGAAGGCGC
```

And when I try,

```
grep '^[^>].*(\n.*)*\s'
```

I get nothing. My intention is "starting from beginning with any character other than the >, followed by any number of characters, followed by( an EOL and any number of character )repeated any number times , and then a space" which describes both sequences individually. How can I fix this ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you considered using `grep -v` to exclude the lines that start with `>`? Something like `grep -v '^>' ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is the trailing space for?  Your sample data doesn't seem to have it, but it could have been trimmed out by stackoverflow's code formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that each valid sequence starts on a new line:

```
\n([GCAT\n]+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU0iY2/2)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...would have to do something with grep matching only one line at a time ?

Comment: grep may not work at all http://stackoverflow.com/a/2686705/244811 across multiple lines, but you could try: `pcregrep -M  '\n([GCAT\n]+)' myinput.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your description what your desired output shall look like. Since you stated that your first command

```
grep '^[^>].*'
```

returned the output as "block", I will assume that you do **not** want the output as a block. I am further going to assume that by block you mean that the sequence contains newlines, hence the newlines shall be cut out.

You also stated that your input data separates the sequences by a trailing space. This space is not contained in the sample data that you posted. I am going to assume that it just got lost while you posted the sample data.

The following *sed* command (GNU sed version 4.2.2) will return each sequence on its own line:

```
sed -n '/^>/b; H;/ $/{g;s/\n//gp;z;h}' input_file # print each block on its own  line
```

If you do not want any newlines at all in your output, i.e., all sequences shall be returned in one single line, separated by the whitespace, then this *sed* will do the job:

```
sed -n '/^>/d; H;${g;s/\n//gp}' input_file # print single line, separating blocks by space
```

If neither of the above *sed* instructions meets your requirements then you really need to provide some sample output. You should also clarify whether my assumption of what you mean by block is correct or wrong. The role of the trailing space that you mentioned is, since it is missing in your sample, also unclear.

**UPDATE**
If you want to filter for the sequences separately then you cannot do it with
grep. But you could use this little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=""
declare -i match

usage() {
echo
echo "usage: gengrep.sh -f file -m n -h"
echo "-f    search in 'file'"
echo "-m    the 'n'-th sequence to match"
echo "-h    display this text and exit"
echo
}

while getopts "f:m:" option; do
    case "${option}" in
        f ) file="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        m ) if [[ ${OPTARG} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
                match="${OPTARG}"
            else
                echo "Argument for -m must be positive integer" >&2
                usage
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        h ) usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        * ) usage
            exit 2
            ;;
    esac
done

awk -v m=$((match)) '/^>/ {if (++i > m) exit;next} i==m' "${file}"

exit 0
```

Save it, e.g. as `gengrep.sh`, and give it execute permissions via `chmod 0775 gengrep.sh`. Then you can call it like this

```
./gengrep.sh -f path/to/file -m 2
```

and it will return the 2nd sequence only.
If you store the script location within your $PATH then you do not have to call it by its full pathname.

Comment: I updated the questions with the current output and the expected output. Is there a way to do this with just grep ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you really want is to "unwrap" the DNA sequences. The easiest way to do that is with `tr`. In order to effectively do it, though, you can use `sed` to install a *marker character* in places where you want to edit (this is much like how DNA works, so you should get it! :-)

```
cat sequences                  \
| sed -e '/^>/s/^(.*)$/@\1@/'  \
| tr -d '\n'                   \
| tr '@' '\n'                  \
> sequences.new
```

Comment: Sed take files names on the command line: `sed '/.../' sequences`

Comment: Doing that would have two effects, both negative. First, it would make it harder to reorder the lines. Second, it would "hide" the filename or names in a bunch of line noise. And as the sed expressions got longer and more complex, the problem would get worse.

Comment: If you want you can use `< filename sed '/.../'` or `sed filename -e '/.../'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try awk:

```
awk '/^[^>]/{x = x $0} /^>/{if(x != ""){print x}; x = ""} END{print x}' seq.fasta
```

Explanation:

1. store sequence in `x`;
2. print stored sequence and reset it when new sequence starts;
3. print stored sequence in the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to remove the text for any line beginning with `>` but keep the newline:

```
sed 's/^>.*//' filename
```

same result using awk:

```
awk '/^>/ {$0=""} 1' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This command will match all the lines which contain just the letters `G`, `A` `C`, `T`, thereby avoiding the undesirable lines that start with `>`.

```
grep "^[GACT]+$"
```