# Search two patterns on two consecutive lines and print n lines before the match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to grep or search using shell commands for two consecutive lines that match two different patterns, e.g match for line1: "abc", for line2: "def". So, for the following text there should be one match: lines 4 and 5.

```
1234
abc-noise
6789
abc-noise
def-noise
def-noise
1234
```

When I find such a match I want to print it including N lines before the match. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: Did you make an attempt using `grep`, `sed` or any tools. Post your research efforts

Comment: Not much to show. I tried 'grep -B1 def | grep -A1 abc' , but then got stuck with how I could also get the N lines before the match. Where -B1 outputs also 1 line before the match, and -A1 1 line after the match

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep

Comment: Not really a duplicate. The tricky and different part is I also need to output N lines before the consecutive lines match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `GNU grep` in `PCRE` mode, with `-P` flag enabled,

```
grep -ozP ".*abc.*\n.*def.*" file
```

Using `pcregrep` for an input file

```
cat file
1234
abc-noise
6789
abc-noise
def-noise
def-noise
1234
noise-abc-noise
noise-noise-def
```

For multi-line pattern-match, do

```
pcregrep -M  'abc.*\n.*def' file 
abc-noise
def-noise
noise-abc-noise
noise-noise-def
```

And for lines before the pattern match, use the `-B` flag as in `GNU grep`

```
pcregrep -B2 -M  'abc.*\n.*def' file 
abc-noise
6789
abc-noise
def-noise
def-noise
1234
noise-abc-noise
noise-noise-def
```

More about the flags `-M` and `-B` from the `man pcregrep` page,

> -M, --multiline
>                    Allow patterns to match more than one line. When this option is given, patterns may usefully contain  literal  newline  characters  and  internal
>                    occurrences of ^ and $ characters. The output for a successful match may consist of more than one line, the last of which is the one in which the
>                    match ended. If the matched string ends with a newline sequence the output ends at the end of that line.
>
> -B number, --before-context=number
>                    Output number lines of context before each matching line. If filenames and/or line numbers are being output, a hyphen separator is  used  instead
>                    of  a  colon for the context lines. A line containing "--" is output between each group of lines, unless they are in fact contiguous in the input
>                    file.

Comment: Thanks, what about the requirement to print the N lines before the match? I tried your solution with the extra flag -B3, for 3 lines before but it does not work.

Comment: @user2405602: Can you use `pcregrep`? can you see if it is installed? `which pcregrep`?

Comment: , Yes it is installed, but I found a solution using your initial suggestion. Two get 2 more lines before the match you can try:  `grep -ozP ".*\n.*\n.*abc.*\n.*def.*" file `  So just add a `.*\n` for each extra line. Not too elegant but works.

Comment: @user2405602: You don't have to post this is an answer. you can just accept my answer(tick on the left of my answer) to let people know that you have solved the problem. Also refer my solution using pcregrep –

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Inian's great answer, if you want to do search recursively through a whole directory:

```sh
find my_code_dir/ -type f  -name "*.py" -exec pcregrep -B2 -M  'except.*\n.*pass' {} +
```

This particular command will find occurrences lines containing `except` followed immediately by a line containing `pass`, but only in `.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=''
b=''
while read c; do
        a=$b;
        b=$c;
        if [ `echo "$a" |grep "abc"` ] & [ `echo "$b" |grep "def"` ]; then
                echo $a;
                echo $b;
                break;
        fi
done
```

Launch:

```
$./find2pat
wegweg
egwergwerg
sdfabcerg
rrheedef4
```

Output:

```
sdfabcerg
rrheedef4
```

Comment: Thanks, same comment here, what about the requirement to print the N lines before the match?