# grep (bash) multi-line pattern

Tags: bash, unix, grep, multiline

In bash (4.3.46(1)) I have some multi-line so called fasta records where each record is initiated by on line with  >name and the following lines DNA sequence ([AGCTNacgtn]), here three records:

```
>chr1
AGCTACTTTT
AGGGNGGTNN
>chr2
TTGNACACCC
TGGGGGAGTA
>chr3
TGACGTGGGT
TCGGGTTTTT
```

How do I use bash grep to get the second record ? In other languages one might use:

```
>chr2\n([AGCTNagctn]*\n)*
```

In Bash I was trying to use the ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep) (among other SOs). This did not work:

```
grep -zo '>chr2[AGCTNacgtn]+' file
```

Result should be:

```
>chr2
TTGNACACCC
TGGGGGAGTA
```

**SOLUTION**

On my system this was the solution (Almost Cyrus' below, i.e. with out the pipe to a second `grep .` ):

```
grep -Pzo '>chr1\n[AGCTNacgtn\n]+' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Pzo '>chr2\n[AGCTNacgtn\n]+' file | grep .
```

Output:

```
>chr2
TTGNACACCC
TGGGGGAGTA
```

Comment: Oh, I thought  -z made `\n` not necessary ?

Comment: Only `grep -Pzo '>chr2\n[AGCTNacgtn\n]+' file` work - with the final `grep .` my system says "Binary file (standard input) matches" whatever that means.

Comment: I've got '>chr2(\n[^>\n]+)+' --> no trailing new line

Comment: @user3375672: Okay. I rolled my answer back to previous version.

Comment: @silel: It might depend on grep‘s version. I used version 2.6.3.

Comment: @Cyrus I certainly hope it does not depend on `grep`'s version (the regex grammar is the same) modulo any bug. My regex is actually different. With it you don't need to pipe to another `grep` process.

Comment: @silel: Thank you. I'd overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v n=2 -v RS='(^|\n)>' 'NR==n+1{print ">" $0}' file    
>chr2
TTGNACACCC
TGGGGGAGTA
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install the [FAST](https://metacpan.org/release/FAST) perl package. It contains many utilities directly usable from the shell for dealing with `fasta` files, like [fashead](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/FAST/bin/fashead) or [fastail](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/FAST/bin/fastail) (and [much more](https://metacpan.org/source/DHARD/FAST-1.06/README))

after installing it is simple as:

```
fashead -n2 fastafile | fastail -n1
```

output

```
>chr2
TTGNA.....
```

or even simpler

```
fasgrep chr2 fastafile
```

with the same output...

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
grep 'chr2' -A 2 file
>chr2
TTGNACACCC
TGGGGGAGTA
```

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for working with multi-line records is `awk`.

In your case:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"} NR==2 {print RS$0}' input.txt
```

#### input.txt

```
>chr1
AGCTACTTTT
AGGGNGGTNN
>chr2
TTGNACACCC
TGGGGGAGTA
>chr3
TGACGTGGGT
TCGGGTTTTT
```

#### Explanation:

`BEGIN{RS=">"}` Initially set record separator to `">"`

`NR==2` filter for record #2 only

`{print RS$0}` print record #2 with the missing record separator back

Answer (score 0):

Created sedgrep mixed version to support in generic way...
You could use this sedgrep shell command available at
https://github.com/iamdvr/sedgrep-shell-util

Direct Link: https://github.com/iamdvr/sedgrep-shell-util/blob/main/sedgrep

For your case direct command is this...

```
cat <FILE_NAME> | sed -nr ':main; /^>.*chr2/ { :loop; p; n; /^>/ b main; b loop} '
```

sedgrep usage is as follows...

```
Default NEW_LINE_PATTERN is ^\[
Usage : 
    cat {INPUT_FILE_NAME}  | sedgrep  {NEW_LINE_PATTERN} {THREAD_OR_SEARCH_PATTERN} 
    cat {INPUT_FILE_NAME}  | sedgrep  {THREAD_OR_SEARCH_PATTERN} 
    sedgrep {NEW_LINE_PATTERN} {THREAD_OR_SEARCH_PATTERN} {INPUT_FILE_NAME}
    sedgrep {THREAD_OR_SEARCH_PATTERN} {INPUT_FILE_NAME}
Example : 
    cat sampleInput.log | sedgrep 2016-05-23 DB_CONN
    cat sampleInput.log | sedgrep DB_CONN
    sedgrep 2016-05-23 DB_CONN sampleInput.log
    sedgrep DB_CONN sampleInput.log
```