# How to grep a file for a specific string, and also include a variable number of lines after that match another string

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to create a shell script that would read through code and pull out sections.

An example of the code would be:

```
method_name1()
  [Marker] CODE-1234
    # Comment 1
    # Comment 2
  code...

method_name2()
  code...

method_name3()
  [Marker] CODE-456 possible other text
    # Comment 1
  code...

method_name4()
  [Marker] CODE-ABC
  code...
```

So what I'm trying to do is grep through all the source code looking for `[Marker]  CODE-` and then also collect all of the following lines that start with some whitespace followed by a pound comment.

Not all methods would have a marker, not all markers have comments, and there can be one or more lines that make up the comment.

There is the grep parameter -A which gets lines after a match, but it is always for a specific number of lines, whereas this code could have zero to a hundred lines of comments after.

I've thought about trying -B 1 to get the method name and -A 5 to just always get 5 lines and then separately parse them for the `#` symbol, but I just think there should be another/cleaner way.

The end result would be a simple to read table such as:

```
| method       | marker    | comments                           |
|--------------|-----------|------------------------------------|
| method_name1 | CODE-1234 | Comment 1. Comment 2.              |
| method_name3 | CODE-456  | (possible other text) Comment 1.   |
| method_name4 | CODE-ABC  | --                                 |
```

So it is possible to "double grep"?

Comment: If posix grep had multi-line flag it'd be easy... Do you have the option of using `pcregrep` or `sed` from [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)? Edit: [-z will put it all on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398476/5514077) so you can make a multiline regex.

Answer (score 1):

This one will search for exactly Marker, match that line, and all lines after it starting with some spaces followed by #. It will stop a match when it reaches the next [ or a line not started with #.

**Notice** that it does not match the final `# And this` line because it came after a non-commented (#) line.

Here's my regex and it's output:

```
$ grep -Pzo '\[Marker\].*(\n *#.*)*[^\[]' test

1:[Marker] CODE-1234 possible other text
    # Comment 1
    # Comment 2

1:[Marker] Test
    # This
```

Here's the test file:

```
[Marker] CODE-1234 possible other text
    # Comment 1
    # Comment 2

[Mark] Test
    # This

[Marker] Test
    # This
    Not this
    # And this
```