# Searching for an exact content of a file in another file using a shell script

Tags: shell, grep, comparison

I have a file containing a license header. For example:

```
/*
 * first line 
 * second line
 */
```

I would like to search for the exact content only in the first 4 lines of my source files.
I tried to use

> grep -x -Ff "$license_file" "$c_file"

but unfortunately grep searches every line and not the whole content, so it can find, for example, the line "/*" in the middle of a file.
How can I search for the whole content?
Thank you!

Comment: Not clear, could you please do mention expected output in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it hard to grep a multi-line pattern. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686705/5223223) expalined, you probably need to use `pcregrep`:

```sh
pcregrep -M -f "$license_file" "$c_file"
```

This however has some problems in it because it neither check the position (file start in your case) nor the pattern is for multi-line form. First, the content in `$license_file` should be like

```
line 1\nline2\nline 3\nline 4\n
```

So if you can edit the content of `$license_file` to the required format then the problem can be proceeded as

```sh
pcregrep -HMf"$license_file" --line-offsets "$c_file" | grep -o "^$c_file:1:" | sed 's/...$//'
```

The `--line-offsets` option will report the matching line number, so we grep line number 1 and strip the line number to report the matching filename. (Because we know the line number=1 and content is that in `$license_file` so I suppose you want to report the matching filenames.)

If you may not edit `$license_file` you could replace it by `sed`:

```sh
pcregrep -HMf <(sed -En '1h;2,4H;4{x;s/\n|$/\\n/g;p}' "$license_file") --line-offsets "$c_file" | grep -o "^$c_file:1:" | sed 's/...$//'
```

Comment: Unfortunately pcregrep does not work in my environment. I get the error message "error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1"

Comment: Try install `pcre`, `libpcre`, or `libpcre3`. (I think it should be `libpcre3` but you can see if it has a different name in your distribution.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm able to use pcregrep. I've edited the license_file but it still can't find the pattern in the given c file. It works when license_file contains one word, but it stops working when the file contains two words. Does it have any problem with spaces? What am I missing?

Comment: Um, the `line 1` example above works for me. Can you try generating a text file by `seq -f 'line %.0f' 5 > tmp_file` and putting `line 1\nline2\nline 3\nline 4\n` in the pattern file?

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, which version of OS & pcregep do you use? My pcregrep is version 8.39 2016-06-14.

Comment: One more to try: `pcregrep -HM $(cat "$license_file") "$c_file"`. If none works, post sample content so that we can see what's wrong.