# Unable to remove entry from a file using Ansible regex

Tags: regex, grep, ansible, regex-negation, regex-group

Note: i m seeking solution for Ansible. Here is the issue description:

I have a file filedet.yml as below, however realtime this yaml may contain many more IP and file details.

```
---
10.9.9.111:
  /tmp/test.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb

  /tmp/best.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb

10.8.8.44:
  /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
    hash: 1746f03d57491b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2

  /tmp/conf/httpd.conf:
    hash: 1746f03d57491b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2
```

I wish to extract a particular IP and the file details so that it can be removed from the yaml using `state: absent` attribute . Thus, the desired regex should return the below:

```
10.9.9.111:
  /tmp/test.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954e

  /tmp/best.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb
```

I decided to have the start pattern as '10.9.9.111' and search until there are no spaces or newlines which means until it gets to the next IP.

I prepared the below regex and it shows correct, desired FULL Text match on http://regex101.com. See snapshot.

Regex query below:

```
[^#](^10.9.9.111:)(.|\n)*^(?!( |\n))
```

[image]

The same regex works fine with `grep -Pzo` and returns the desired string. However, the regex fails to work with ansible's `lineinfile` module as it does not yeild any results.

i want this regex or any other solution to work with Ansible so i can remove the given IP and it's file details from the yaml

Ansible:

```
   - name: "Remove entry from file."
     lineinfile:
       path: "/app/filedet.yaml"
       regexp: "[^#](^10.9.9.111:)(.|\n)*^(?!( |\n))"
       state: absent
```

Can you please suggest what is the issue here ?

Comment: In POSIX *REs, circumflex in the middle of a regular expression matches a regular circumflex; it loses its meaning as a special character. And IIRC a POSIX grep can't perform a multiline match

Comment: `grep` only examines one line at a time; there is no way really to specify matches which should straddle newlines with this tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

Comment: I m not seeking a solution for grep but seeking a regex that will work with Ansible

Comment: `grep -Pzo` works for me. But how can i get it to work with Ansible's lineinfile ?

Comment: Shall i repost specific to Ansible?

Comment: @Ashar, you might want to remove the irrelevant info about grep and POSIX. It's all about Python regex. And, in the end, it's not about regex at all, I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I wish to extract an IP and the file details."*

A: Use [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task). For example

```
    - include_vars:
        file: filedet.yml
        name: my_dict
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_dict['10.9.9.111'] }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": {
        "/tmp/best.jar": {
            "hash": "e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb"
        }, 
        "/tmp/test.jar": {
            "hash": "e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb"
        }
    }
```

---

> Q: *"Remove an entry from the file."*

A: Use template. For example

```
$ cat filedet.yml.j2
{% for item in my_dict_keys %}
{{ item }}:
  {{ my_dict[item]|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
{% endfor %}
```

The task below

```
    - set_fact:
        my_dict_keys:
          - "10.8.8.44"
    - template:
        src: filedet.yml.j2
        dest: filedet.yml
```

gives

```
$ cat filedet.yml
10.8.8.44:
  /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
      hash: 1746f03d57491b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2
  /tmp/conf/httpd.conf:
      hash: 1746f03d57491b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2
```

---

Notes:

- It's a bad idea to use `lineinfile` for this purpose
- Data in the question is not valid YAML. The key is repeating

```
10.9.9.111:
  /tmp/test.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb
  /tmp/test.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb
```

Comment: can you get the template to include all ip and file details except the one i wish to remove inthis case 10.9.9.111

Comment: No. I can't. The template is fine as it is. Instead, you can test what you want first and update your question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Vladimir i updated the question with all the details. Can you have a look ?

Comment: New post with refined description here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948370/remove-contents-of-a-include-vars-file-using-ansible