# How can I compare grep line numbers in a conditional statement in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, git-bash

I am building a git pre-commit hook to reject commits that contain string 'X'. I have a working version below.

```
#!/bin/sh

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

for FILE in `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM`; do
    if [ "grep 'X' $FILE" ]
    then
    echo -e "${RED}[REJECTED]${NC}"
    exit 1
fi
done
exit
```

What I would like to do is change the condition to look for string 'X', and if found, look for string 'Y' exactly 3 lines later. For example, X is on line 7 and Y is on line 10. I only want to reject commits with files containing strings 'X' and 'Y' separated by 3 lines. I have tried some funky things like:

```
if [ "grep -n 'X' $FILE" ] + 3 -eq [ "grep -n 'Y' $FILE" ]
```

How can I create the conditional I need? How best to generalise this?

Comment: The conditional is currently checking if the string `"grep 'X' $FILE"` is empty, which it never is, so the condition will always be true. You want something like `if grep -q 'X' "$FILE"` instead (no `[ ... ]` required).

Comment: And regarding the question about matching files with a pattern that spans multiple lines, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686147/3266847

Comment: Hi Benjamin W., I believe you and you are likely right in theory. In practice, in this example, I've tested this logic with two files, one of which contains 'X' and the other which does not. The condition works as I expect.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `[ \`grep 'X' $FILE\` ]`? I am absolutely positive that testing a non-empty string like `[ "grep 'X' $FILE" ]` has a successful exit status 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can pull it off, but there might be simpler ways:

```
for FILE in `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM`; do
    nl $FILE | grep 'X' - | while read line blah; do
        lines=$( head -n $(( $line + 3 )) $FILE | tail -n 1 | grep 'Y' | wc -l )
        if [ $lines -gt 0 ]; then
            echo you got it baby, on line $line for file $FILE
        fi
    done
done
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: For completeness, I will check each solution and vote/accept accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -A` to extract the three lines following X, and then check the last line for Y:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
chunk=$(grep -A3 X "$file")
size=$(wc -l <<< "$chunk")
lastline=${chunk##*$'\n'}

if ((size == 4)) && grep -q Y <<< "$lastline" ; then
    echo Found both X and Y
fi
```

The size check is needed for the case when the Y follows X at the end of the file with less than two lines in between.

Answer (score 0):

use sed to check for a pattern occurring n lines after your first pattern

```
sed -n '/<pattern1>/{n;n;n; /<patter2>/p}' $FILE
```