# Match substring with regex inside file with bash

Tags: bash

I have a following text file that contains content:

```
┌─ This is folder description
│
├─ ##### ─────── Magenta 
│
├─ Size ──────── 245.7 GiB
│
├─ URL ───────── https://www.google.com
│
│
├─ Video ─────── 23.976fps
│
├─ Audio ─────┬─ French 
│             │         
│             │
│             └─ German
│
├─ Subtitles ─── French, German, Italian, C#
```

I want to verify if there is `French` between *Audio* and *Subtitles*, I don't care rest.

I tried:

```
grep -E 'Audio(.*)(French|Franz?)(.*)Sub(s|(titles?)|(titulos))' test.txt
```

But no match. I'm pretty sure that is something wrong in using grep. Can lead me to correct way to do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` reads 1 line at a time by default so you can't do a multi-line match on a single line. Using GNU grep for `-z` (to read the whole file at one time) and `-o` (as I'm guessing at what output you want):

```
$ grep -Ezo 'Audio(.*)(French|Franz?)(.*)Sub(s|(titles?)|(titulos))' test.txt
Audio ─────┬─ French
│             │
│             │
│             └─ German
│
├─ Subtitles
```

Alternatively, using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END {
        if ( match(rec,/Audio(.*)(French|Franz?)(.*)Sub(s|(titles?)|(titulos))/) ) {
            print substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        }
    }
' test.txt
Audio ─────┬─ French
│             │
│             │
│             └─ German
│
├─ Subtitles
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always 2 audios than it could be simple:

```
grep Audio -A3 file.txt | grep French
```

Adding `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Audio/,/Subtitles/p' file.txt | grep -v Subtitles | grep French
```