# How can I use findstr with newline regular expression

Tags: windows, regex, dos, findstr

I'm on windows dos prompt. I have log file which contains log like:

```
Timestamp: Order received for Item No. 26551
Timestamp: Exception: OutOfRangeException
Timestamp: Message: Inventory Item is not stock. Item No. 23423
Timestamp: Order received for Item No. 23341
```

I want to extract all the item number who has give some sort of exception. I'm using findstr command for this. how can I use newline in my regular expression? I want to all lines which have Exception word and from next line the item no.

any help?

Comment: @moderator: Can I close this question? we are seem to be at dead end.

Answer (score 6):

I've discovered an undocumented feature - FINDSTR *CAN* match new line characters `<CR>` and `<LF>` and continue the match on subsequent lines. But the search string must be specified on the command line, the new line characters must be in variables, and the values must be passed via delayed expansion.

Another complication is the IN() clause of a FOR loop is executed in a separate implicit CMD session, and the delayed expansion must be re-enabled. Also, the ! characters must be escaped so that they make it through to the 2nd CMD session.

This little test script does the trick.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"==":doSearch" goto :doSearch

::Define a variable as a LineFeed (0x0A) character
set LF=^


:: The above 2 blank lines MUST be preserved!

::Define a CR variable as a CarriageReturn (0x0D) character
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

set file="test.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cmd /v:on /c^"findstr /rc:"Item No\. .*^!CR^!*^!LF^!.* Exception: " %file%^"') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  set "item=!ln:*Item No. =!"
  echo Item No. !item! had an exception
)
exit /b
```

***EDIT 2015-01-11***

I just reread the question, and realize I got it wrong. The OP wanted the Item Number where the Exception string appears on the prior line (look behind search), but my solution can only find the Item Number where Exception appears on the subsequent line (look ahead search).

Unfortunately, there is no way to get FINDSTR to do a look behind search.

*Under most circumstances, I would delete the answer above, since it does not answer the question. However, this answer does document a novel FINDSTR functionality that had not been described before that could be very useful. The look ahead feature is close enough in concept to the look behind feature that someone that needs it might find the answer via this question, so I plan to keep it.*

I do have a purely script based solution that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward, but it does not use FINDSTR. [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) is a regular expression command line that can easily extract the desired Item Numbers.

```
jrepl "Item No\. (\d+)\r\n.* Exception: " $1 /m /jmatch /f test.txt
```

Comment: Could I customize this to search for a string like `Hello(return)there` in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into the [findstr documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) and I think it is not able to do a multiline search.

Probably you should use more advanced tools like awk, or some versions of grep seems to support multiline regex too.

You can have a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep)

Comment: Thanx. The reason I wanted to do it with dos commands is that I didn't want write heavy code for just parsing a text file. I was kind of aware of that findstr can't do that :( and just wanted to know, if anybody has done that before. Anyway, then I need to run away from it. I did it with VBScript.

Comment: @Morin: You can and should post your solution then. VBScript certainly is a good idea for this. You can even accept your own solution if it's the one that helped you the most (as seems to be the case here). As soon as you have enough reputation, you can then upvote other answers that were also helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Another powershell example, with positive lookbehind:

```
'Timestamp: Order received for Item No. 26551
Timestamp: Exception: OutOfRangeException
Timestamp: Message: Inventory Item is not stock. Item No. 23423
Timestamp: Order received for Item No. 23341
Timestamp: Exception: OutOfRangeException
Timestamp: Message: Inventory Item is not stock. Item No. 23424' | 
  set-content input.txt

get-content -raw input.txt | 
  select-string -allmatches '((?<=exception.*\n.*)\d+)' | 
  % matches | % value
```

```
23423
23424
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Vista or Windows 7 (or if you install it manually on XP), you can use PowerShell for this:

```
$resultlist = new-object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$regex = [regex] '(?m)^.*Exception.*\r\n.*Item No\. (\d+)'
$match = $regex.Match($subject)
while ($match.Success) {
    $resultlist.Add($match.Groups[1].Value) | out-null
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

`$resultlist` will then contain a list of all item numbers that follow a line with `Exception` in it.

Answer (score -3):

If you can download tools, here's a [Ruby for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) command you can use.

```
C:\work>ruby -ne "print gets.split.last if /Exception/" file
23423
C:\work>type file
Timestamp: Order received for Item No. 26551
Timestamp: Exception: OutOfRangeException
Timestamp: Message: Inventory Item is not stock. Item No. 23423
Timestamp: Order received for Item No. 23341

C:\work>ruby -ne "print gets.split.last if /Exception/" file
23423
```

Comment: That's what I didn't want. I just wanted to parse a text file with whatever I have on a client's machine. Thanx for your answer, though