# option to disable gcc `note:`s

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to disable gcc `note:`s. By notes I mean when you get an error or warning and gcc gives you some extra information about it. So this option would shorten

```
test.c:3:0: warning: "FOO" redefined
#define FOO 2

test.c:2:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define FOO 1
```

to just

```
test.c:3:0: warning: "FOO" redefined
#define FOO 2
```

I'll occasionally get a wall of `note:`s when just an the error would be more clear and it would be convenient to skip over them

Comment: If all else fails there is always `gcc ... | grep -v "note:"`..

Comment: unfortunately I'm using a windows machine with mingw right now, otherwise that would be a handy trick for me

Comment: Well, there is always `gcc ... | findstr /V "note:"`..

Comment: @doynax modified slightly to `2>&1 gcc test.c | findstr /V "note:"` since apparently gcc goes to stderr. Unfortunately this solution does not remove all lines associated with the note, just the note line itself. Though as you said, it helps if all else fails

Comment: Fair point. [While possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631752/how-can-i-use-findstr-with-newline-regular-expression) it does get a tad messy, so may be better off writing a small filtering utility of your own.