# How to (e) grep XML for certain tag content?

Tags: xml, regex, grep

How can I (e)grep all content between a certain tag block?

Assume input file below, I want to get as output all characters between the B-tags so:

```
<B><C>Test</C></B>
<B>Test2</B>
```

I tried the following grep to search all XML files with the content between the `<B>` and `</B>` tags.

```
grep '<B>.*</B>' *.xml
```

but it did not work.

For the following input:

```
<A>
 <B>
  <C>Test</C>
 </B>
 <D>
 </D>
 <B>
    Test2
 </B>
</A>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Regular expressions (and particularly the wildcards) only match on a single line. Why not just search for <B> and then search for </B>. But you probably want to handle nested tags, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file ? Use pcregrep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep)

Comment: @PauliL: Wildcards aren't the problem, it's grep itself that confines each match to a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Use awk:

```
awk '/<B>/,/<\/B>/'
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with xml files, the best way is to use xml tools.

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//B' file.xml
```

xmllint from [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/):

```
xmllint --xpath '//B' file.xml
```