# Scope of grep with regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to use a regular expression with grep command of Linux

```
(^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$))
```

When I am trying it out at https://www.regextester.com with the contents of a file, I am getting the required result, i.e., the required fields are getting matched but when I am trying to use it as

```
grep '(^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$))' file1
```

all it gives me is a null!

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pcregrep -M  '(^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$))'
```

did the trick :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `grep` understands character classes like `\w` and `\s`.  Try using either `grep -E` or `egrep`.  (`grep -E` is equivalent to `egrep`, `egrep` is just shorter to type.)

So your command would be:

```
egrep '(^\s*\*\s*\[ \][^\*]+?(\w*\:[^\*]+\d$)|([^\*]+[.]com[.]au$))' file1
```

Comment: thats cool but how do i do a multiline search?
assuming grep works line by line..
i want a multi line search..
so is there any solution?

Comment: @KiranVemuri That's a different question that the one you posed here.  That topic is covered by [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep)

Comment: By default, egrep doesn't understand \s or \w either. However, you can use the --perl-regexp flag if PCRE has been compiled in.

Comment: @CodeGnome RTM: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions

Comment: Although, to be fair, it does say that it should work for `grep` as well.  I'm pretty sure in older versions that was an `egrep` extension.

Answer (score 0):

[`grep(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) uses [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) by default, and [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_0) when used with the `-E`
option.

In [POSIX Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) non-special characters have undefined behaviour when escaped, ex. `\s`, and there is no syntax for non-greedy matching, ex. `+?`.  Furthermore, in BREs, the `+` and `|` operators are not available, and parenthesis must be escaped to perform grouping.

The [POSIX character classes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) `[[:space:]]` and `[[:alnum:]_]` are a portable alternatives to `\s` and `\w` respectively.

Excluding the next matching character from a repetition can be used to emulate non-greedy matching, ex. `[^*]+?\w*:` is equivalent
to `[^*[:alnum:]_:]+[[:alnum:]_]*:`.

The given regular expression can be represented as multiple BREs:

```
grep -e '^[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]\{1,\}\[ \][^*[:alnum:]_+]\{1,\}[[:alnum:]_]*:[^*]\{1,\}[[:digit:]]$' \
    -e '[^*]\{1,\}\.com\.au$' file1
```

or an ERE:

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]*\*[[:space:]]*\[ \][^*[:alnum:]_:]+[[:alnum:]_]*:[^*]+[[:digit:]]$|[^*]+\.com\.au$' \
    file1
```

Note that the GNU implementation of `grep(1)` allows for both short character classes (`\s` and `\w`) and non-greedy repetition (`+?`), as non-portable extensions.