# Scripting - copy line and the second line IF the second line has a string

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, awk

I have a problem where I have a large amount of files that I need to scan and return a line and its following line, but only when the following line begins with a string.

```
String one - line one must begin with 'Bill'
String two - line two must begin with 'Jones'.
```

If these two criteria are matched, it returns the two lines. Repeat for the whole file.

ie. original file:

```
Edith Blue
Edith Green
Edith Red
Bill Blue
Jones Red
Edith Green
Bill Green
Edith Red
Jones Green
Bill Blue
```

I'd want it to return only:

```
Bill Blue
Jones Red
```

Any ideas? No idea where to begin with this, I only have basic scripting skills with sed/awk etc... At the moment I am using this to get the filename and its following line, but it is giving me too much useless information that I have to strip off with other sed commands.

```
grep -A 1 "^Bill" * > test.txt
```

I guess there's a far more elegant way of getting only the lines I need. Any help would be lovely!

Comment: What you really need is pcregrep. Have a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep/152711#152711

Answer (score 2):

As an extension of your initial approach, a simple solution is to grep lines starting with "Bill" returning one after, then find lines starting with "Jones" returning one before....

```
grep -A1 "^Bill" myfile.txt | grep "^Jones" -B1
```

Output:

```
Bill Blue
Jones Red
```

Side note: as a true test, your input file should probably have some lines where `Bill` and `Jones` are not at the start of the line...

```
Edith Blue
Edith Jones
Edith Red
Bill Blue
Jones Red
Edith Bill
Bill Jones
Edith Red
Jones Green
Bill Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getline()` instruction of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for each line that begins with `Bill`:

```
awk '
    $1 ~ /^Bill/ { 
        getline l
        if ( l ~ /^Jones/ ) { 
            printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, l 
        } 
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
Bill Blue
Jones Red
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is another way using awk with a flag:

```
$ awk '$1=="Bill"{p=1;a=$0;next};$1=="Jones"&&p{print a;print};{p=0}' file
Bill Blue
Jones Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple python script:

```
FILE = 'test.text'

f = open(FILE,'r')

one = 'Bill'
two = 'Jones'

prev = ''

for line in f:
    if prev.startswith(one) and line.startswith(two):
        print prev,line.rstrip()
    prev = line
```

Yields:

```
python FileRead.py
Bill Blue
Jones Red
```

Comment: (Probably more efficient to use `.startswith` rather than `split` and test?)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '$!N;/^Bill.*\nJones/p;D' file
```