# ACK-GREP ignore whitespaces

Tags: regex, grep, ack

I've switched to ACK-GREP recently (bye, bye standard grep) and the only thing I'm missing is the option to ignore whitespaces while searching.

Example:

```
@param(
    'lol', int, "Foo bar",
    can=False, hasBurger=True
)
```

and I want to find it by

> ack @param('lol'

What do I have to change/add in .ackrc to force this behawior?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It is not due to the space but the new line. From the FAQ at the man page:

```
*Can I do multi-line regexes?*
   No, ack does not support regexes that match multiple lines.  Doing so would require 
   reading in the entire file at a time.
```

However, you can build your own pipe and delete all spaces:

```
 cat YOURFILE | tr -d [:space:] | ack --type=TYPE -o PATTERN
```

But I guess, this is not exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: Now it does find something but I lose the info about line number.
BTW Can I cat all the files and subfolders recursively this way?

Comment: Regarding recursion: you could use `xargs`: `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cat ...`.  However, maybe you should have a look at [pcregrep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep).