# Grep search strings with line breaks with the Find command

Tags: unix, grep, find

I'm trying to search within all settings.ini files and determine which of them contain a specific multiline string.

My directory structures look like this

```
/
|-- folder
|---- settings.ini
|-- folder
|---- settings.ini
|-- folder
|---- settings.ini
|-- folder
|---- settings.ini
.
.
.
```

The string I am trying to find looks like this

```
[NeatFeature]
Enabled=1
```

The files themselves will contain either Enabled=1 or Enabled=0

I'm able to get a single line search working like this

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name 'settings.ini' -exec grep '\[TransactionalMessageSearch\]' {} +
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to also include the Enabled=1 portion.  I can't just search for that on it's own as that patter occurs multiple times throughout the files under different headings.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file ? Use pcregrep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep)

Comment: pcregrep is unavailable to me unfortunately

Comment: That's not the only method listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a suggestion by Mark, I was able to then pipe the output and get grep through that to get to the result set I was looking for

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name 'settings.ini' -exec grep -HA 1 '\[TransactionalMessageSearch\]' {} \; | grep 'Enabled=1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-A` to add some lines after the match maybe:

```
grep -A 2 xyz file
```

It depends how many lines there may be between the search string and the additional information.

Comment: Thanks Mark I was able to use this to build a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name 'settings.ini' | xagrs grep 'Enabled=1'
```

Comment: This wont work because there may be Enabled=1 elsewhere in the file, but not under the header important to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Perl Method**

```
perl -0777 -ne 's/.*\[TransactionalMessageSearch]\nEnabled=(\d)//s;print $1' settings.ini
```

**Original Answer**

You can also do this with `gawk` and test more than one file per invocation, using `find`'s `+` feature:

Save this as a file called `FeatureTest`

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'=' '/\[TransactionalMessageSearch\]/{armed=1} armed==1 && /Enabled/{print FILENAME":"$2;armed=0;nextfile}' "$@"
```

then do this to make it executable

```
chmod +x FeatureTest
```

then you can do:

```
find . -name 'settings.ini' -exec ./FeatureTest {} +
```

The `nextfile` function is part of GNU awk, and I don't know of a way to do that without, so you would have to settle for the slower version as follows if you do not have GNU awk.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'=' '/\[TransactionalMessageSearch\]/{armed=1} armed==1 && /Enabled/{print FILENAME":"$2;exit}' "$1"
```

and use it with:

```
find . -name 'settings.ini' -exec ./FeatureTest {} \;
```

The `awk` script basically looks for the string `[Transact...]` and when it finds it, it arms itself ready for the next occurrence of the word `Enabled`. When it finds that, after being armed, it prints the second field and the filename and moves to the next file (or exits). The fields are separated by an `=` sign because of the `-F` at the start.

Comment: So this works, but not in my environment as I don't have the ability to create the file on this server so need to be able to run it all as one command.