# multiline search in grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have made a text file of nmap's output and i was trying to find only those ip whose port are open
and when i am using grep i am not getting the desired output only one of the item is i am able to get either ip or the text open

data:

```
Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.83 
Host is up (0.050s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.87
Host is up (0.049s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.89
Host is up (0.051s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.90
Host is up (0.050s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.93
Host is up (0.051s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.96
Host is up (0.051s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.100
Host is up (0.054s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Just curious. What do you plan to do with those open ports? :) It's also interesting that most are http services :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -v RS="" '/ open /{print $5}' file
xxx.xxx.xxx.93
```

It prints the `ip` (column no 5) only if the certain block contains the text `open`

Answer (score 1):

After `awk` and `grep`  perl too:

```
perl -00 -lanE 'say $_ if m/open/' < file
```

prints:

```
Nmap scan report for xxx.xxx.xxx.93
Host is up (0.051s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

or

```
perl -00 -lanE 'say $F[4] if m/open/' < file
```

prints

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.93
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always 4 lines per block and the word `open` is in the last line, you can do:

```
grep -B4 open file
```

and it will show the 4 lines before the word `open`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `awk`? This will report the IP address the first time an open port is encountered in the `nmap` output:

```
sh$ awk '$3=="report"{ IP = $5 } $2=="open"&&IP { print IP; IP="" }' nmap.out
xxx.xxx.xxx.93
```